# How do I remove leading whitespace in Python?

Tags: python, string, whitespace, trim

I have a text string that starts with a number of spaces, varying between 2 & 4.

What is the simplest way to remove the leading whitespace? (ie. remove everything before a certain character?)

```
"  Example"   -> "Example"
"  Example  " -> "Example  "
"    Example" -> "Example"
```

Answer (score 443, accepted):

The [`lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) method will remove leading whitespaces, newline and tab characters on a string beginning:

```
>>> '     hello world!'.lstrip()
'hello world!'
```

**Edit**

[As balpha pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959215/removing-starting-spaces-in-python#comment768038_959216), in order to remove *only* spaces from the beginning of the string, `lstrip(' ')` should be used:

```
>>> '   hello world with 2 spaces and a tab!'.lstrip(' ')
'\thello world with 2 spaces and a tab!'
```

Related question:

- [Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Note, though, that lstrip while remove leading *whitespace* which may be more that spaces (tabs etc). That's usually what you want. If you want to remove spaces and spaces only, call " bla".lstrip(" ")

Comment: It might be useful to note for new Python programmers that strings in python are immutable, so if you're working with a string 'string_a', you might think  string_a.lstrip() will change the string itself, but in fact you'd need to assign the value of string_a.lstrip() to either itself or a new variable, e.g. "string_a = string_a.lstrip()".

Comment: note: as there is lstrip() there is also strip() and rstrip()

Answer (score 121):

The function `strip` will remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```
my_str = "   text "
my_str = my_str.strip()
```

will set `my_str` to `"text"`.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to cut the whitespaces before and behind the word, but keep the middle ones. 
You could use:

```
word = '  Hello World  '
stripped = word.strip()
print(stripped)
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this _does_ print `'Hello World'` with the middle space intact, for anyone wondering, I guess it has been voted down because the original question was specifically asking to remove _leading_ spaces.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

Print Is A Function
The print statement has been replaced with a print() function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement (PEP 3105).

Comment: @mbrandeis How is that statement relevant here?

Answer (score 18):

The question doesn't address multiline strings, but here is how you would strip leading whitespace from a multiline string using [python's standard library textwrap module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent). If we had a string like:

```
s = """
    line 1 has 4 leading spaces
    line 2 has 4 leading spaces
    line 3 has 4 leading spaces
"""
```

if we `print(s)` we would get output like:

```
>>> print(s)
    this has 4 leading spaces 1
    this has 4 leading spaces 2
    this has 4 leading spaces 3
```

and if we used `textwrap.dedent`:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print(textwrap.dedent(s))
this has 4 leading spaces 1
this has 4 leading spaces 2
this has 4 leading spaces 3
```

Answer (score 14):

To remove everything before a certain character, use a regular expression:

```
re.sub(r'^[^a]*', '')
```

to remove everything up to the first 'a'. `[^a]` can be replaced with any character class you like, such as word characters.

Comment: I think the guy asked for the "easiest & simplest way"

Comment: True, but he did also (perhaps inadvertantly) ask for the solution for a more general problem, "ie. remove everything before a certain character?", and this is that more general solution.

Answer (score 5):

My personal favorite for any string handling is strip, split and join (in that order):

```
>>> ' '.join("   this is my  badly spaced     string   ! ".strip().split())
'this is my badly spaced string !'
```

In general it can be good to apply this for all string handling.

This does the following:

1. First it strips - this removes leading and ending spaces.
2. Then it splits - it does this on whitespace by default (so it'll even get tabs and newlines). The thing is that this returns a list.
3. Finally join iterates over the list and joins each with a single space in between.

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions when cleaning the text is the best practice

```
def removing_leading_whitespaces(text):
     return re.sub(r"^\s+","",text)
```

Apply the above function

```
removing_leading_whitespaces("  Example")
"  Example"   -> "Example"

removing_leading_whitespaces("  Example  ")
"  Example  " -> "Example  "

removing_leading_whitespaces("    Example")
"    Example" -> "Example"
```