# Python regex - r prefix

Tags: python, regex, string, literals, prefix

Can anyone explain why example 1 below works, when the `r` prefix is not used?
I thought the `r` prefix must be used whenever escape sequences are used.
Example 2 and example 3 demonstrate this.

```
# example 1
import re
print (re.sub('\s+', ' ', 'hello     there      there'))
# prints 'hello there there' - not expected as r prefix is not used

# example 2
import re
print (re.sub(r'(\b\w+)(\s+\1\b)+', r'\1', 'hello     there      there'))
# prints 'hello     there' - as expected as r prefix is used

# example 3
import re
print (re.sub('(\b\w+)(\s+\1\b)+', '\1', 'hello     there      there'))
# prints 'hello     there      there' - as expected as r prefix is not used
```

Comment: i think I explain well why raw strings are needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068412/1601580

Answer (score 106):

Because `\` begin escape sequences only when they are valid escape sequences.

```
>>> '\n'
'\n'
>>> r'\n'
'\\n'
>>> print '\n'


>>> print r'\n'
\n
>>> '\s'
'\\s'
>>> r'\s'
'\\s'
>>> print '\s'
\s
>>> print r'\s'
\s
```

> [Unless](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, [escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C. The recognized escape sequences are:
>
> ```
> Escape Sequence   Meaning Notes
> \newline  Ignored  
> \\    Backslash (\)    
> \'    Single quote (')     
> \"    Double quote (")     
> \a    ASCII Bell (BEL)     
> \b    ASCII Backspace (BS)     
> \f    ASCII Formfeed (FF)  
> \n    ASCII Linefeed (LF)  
> \N{name}  Character named name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)  
> \r    ASCII Carriage Return (CR)   
> \t    ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)   
> \uxxxx    Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only) 
> \Uxxxxxxxx    Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (Unicode only) 
> \v    ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)  
> \ooo  Character with octal value ooo
> \xhh  Character with hex value hh
> ```

Never rely on raw strings for path literals, as raw strings have some rather *peculiar* inner workings, known to have bitten people in the ass:

> When an "r" or "R" prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase "n". String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

To better illustrate this last point:

```
>>> r'\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> r'\''
"\\'"
>>> '\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> '\''
"'"
>>> 
>>> r'\\'
'\\\\'
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> print r'\\'
\\
>>> print r'\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print '\\'
\
```

Comment: As a minor fix, `'\s'` (like `r'\s'`) is also represented as `'\\s'`, due to `'\s'` not being a recognized escape sequence.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari I'd swear that the output was correct back when I wrote this answer... Fixed.

Comment: 8 years certainly justify the magical change in python behavior. :D

Answer (score 49):

the 'r' means the the following is a "raw string", ie. backslash characters are treated literally instead of signifying special treatment of the following character.

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

so `'\n'` is a single newline
and `r'\n'` is two characters - a backslash and the letter 'n'
another way to write it would be `'\\n'` because the first backslash escapes the second

an equivalent way of writing this

```
print (re.sub(r'(\b\w+)(\s+\1\b)+', r'\1', 'hello     there      there'))
```

is

```
print (re.sub('(\\b\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+', '\\1', 'hello     there      there'))
```

Because of the way Python treats characters that are not valid escape characters, not all of those double backslashes are necessary - eg `'\s'=='\\s'` however the same is not true for `'\b'` and `'\\b'`. My preference is to be explicit and double all the backslashes.

Comment: If r or R means raw string, then how come the plus sign makes even any sense??! It would literally search for that exact string: "(\b\w+)(\s+\1\b)+". I don't understand your choice of string. Or somehow, regular expressions are a part of raw strings? In which case, I am utterly confused.

Answer (score 6):

Not all sequences involving backslashes are escape sequences. `\t` and `\f` are, for example, but `\s` is not. In a non-raw string literal, any `\` that is not part of an escape sequence is seen as just another `\`:

```
>>> "\s"
'\\s'
>>> "\t"
'\t'
```

`\b` *is* an escape sequence, however, so example 3 fails. (And yes, some people consider this behaviour rather unfortunate.)

Comment: Exactly. Although, @JT, I recommend using '\\s' or r'\s', or you'll probably inadvertently hit some escape sequences that you didn't mean to.

Comment: Indeed: always use raw string literals when you want the string to contain backslashes (as opposed to actually wanting the escape sequences.)

Comment: @Thomas: `r` still escapes some sequences when they appear at the end of the string: `r"\"` is invalid, to do that you have to do `"\\"`. If you do `r"\\"`, you get a `\\ ` printed (`"\\\\"` string). Be careful with that.

Comment: Yes, raw string literals can't end in a single `\\`.

Comment: @Blair/Thomas: thanks - this was the general rule I was following that got me confused in the first place! ... all is clear now, thanks all.

Though in following this rule ... when reading the pattern from a plain text file, how would the pattern be passed on as a raw literal string?

Comment: @JT, if I understand the question correctly, you would just put \s in the plain text file - no interpretation of the string contents would occur when you read it in.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
a = '\''
'
a = r'\''
\'
a = "\'"
'
a = r"\'"
\'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below example:

```
print r"123\n123" 
#outputs>>>
123\n123


print "123\n123"
#outputs>>>
123
123
```