# How to extract the substring between two markers?

Tags: python, string, substring

Let's say I have a string `'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'` and I want to extract just the `'1234'` part.

I only know what will be the few characters directly before `AAA`, and after `ZZZ` the part I am interested in `1234`.

With `sed` it is possible to do something like this with a string:

```
echo "$STRING" | sed -e "s|.*AAA\(.*\)ZZZ.*|\1|"
```

And this will give me `1234` as a result.

How to do the same thing in Python?

Comment: one liner with python 3.8 `text[text.find(start:='AAA')+len(start):text.find('ZZZ')]`

Answer (score 873, accepted):

Using regular expressions - [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for further reference

```
import re

text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'

m = re.search('AAA(.+?)ZZZ', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)

# found: 1234
```

or:

```
import re

text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'

try:
    found = re.search('AAA(.+?)ZZZ', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    # AAA, ZZZ not found in the original string
    found = '' # apply your error handling

# found: 1234
```

Comment: The second solution is better, if the pattern matches most of the time, because its [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: Doesn't the indexing start at 0? So you would need to use group(0) instead of group(1)?

Comment: @Alexander, no, group(0) will return full matched string: AAA1234ZZZ, and group(1) will return only characters matched by first group: 1234

Comment: @Bengt: Why is that? The first solution looks quite simple to me, and it has fewer lines of code.

Comment: Why use `.+?` and not `.*`? Aren't they rather equivalent?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The link I gave hints it: "clean and fast". Basically, it makes exception handling obvious and saves one conditional jump.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye `.+` **must** match something, e.g. the numbers in this example. `.*` **can** match something, but does not have to. E.g. it would match *gfgfdAAAZZZuijjk* too.

Comment: @whirlwin, yes, but I wrote `.+?`, not `.+`. Since the `.+` is followed by a `?`, doesn't that mean that `.+` is optional? I.e. the `.` can occur any number of times, including zero (which is why I think `.+?` should be equivalent to `.*`)? Otherwise, what role does the `?` play in this expression?

Comment: In this expression the ? modifies the + to be non-greedy, ie. it will match any number of times from 1 upwards but as few as possible, only expanding as necessary. without the ?, the first group would match gfgfAAA2ZZZkeAAA43ZZZonife as 2ZZZkeAAA43, but with the ? it would only match the 2, then searching for multiple (or having it stripped out and search again) would match the 43.

Comment: @Bengt: If you go into the exception often, then the if would have been faster. Basically, if you think that it the condition will be met most of the time, go with exception-handling, but if you think it will not be met most of the time, go with `if`. While "try-catch" is considered pythonic by some, in general software engineering it is actually considered to be not great, because it makes functions non-pure.

Comment: @eumiro thanks for your answer.
If the interested part is sure to be decimals then one can use following:  (\d+) instead of (.+?). It is working for me.

Comment: what is the approach if there are multiple matches in string something like 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjkAAA2672ZZZasdcdAAA862ZZZasxawcwcw'? I want to extract every in-between string

Comment: @ShubhankGupta In that case, you can use `re.findall` to find all pattern appearing in that string. Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:~:text=an%20empty%20string.-,re.findall,-(pattern%2C) for more details

Comment: if you are searching something in the file `((.|\n)*)` might be useful to take also new lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 161):

```
>>> s = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
>>> start = s.find('AAA') + 3
>>> end = s.find('ZZZ', start)
>>> s[start:end]
'1234'
```

Then you can use regexps with the re module as well, if you want, but that's not necessary in your case.

Comment: The question seems to imply that the input text will always contain both "AAA" and "ZZZ". If this is not the case, your answer fails horribly (by that I mean it returns something completely wrong instead of an empty string or throwing an exception; think "hello there" as input string).

Comment: @user225312 Is the `re` method not faster though?

Comment: Voteup, but I would use "x = 'AAA' ; s.find(x) + len(x)" instead of "s.find('AAA') + 3" for maintainability.

Comment: If any of the tokens can't be found in the `s`, `s.find` will return `-1`.  the slicing operator `s[begin:end]`  will accept it as valid index, and return undesired substring.

Comment: @confused00 find is much faster than re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find

Answer (score 131):

#### regular expression

```
import re

re.search(r"(?<=AAA).*?(?=ZZZ)", your_text).group(0)
```

The above as-is will fail with an `AttributeError` if there are no "AAA" and "ZZZ" in `your_text`

#### string methods

```
your_text.partition("AAA")[2].partition("ZZZ")[0]
```

The above will return an empty string if either "AAA" or "ZZZ" don't exist in `your_text`.

PS Python Challenge?

Comment: This answer probably deserves more up votes. The string method is the most robust way. It does not need a try/except.

Comment: ... nice, though limited.  partition is not regex based, so it only works in this instance because the search string was bounded by fixed literals

Comment: Great, many thanks! - this works for strings and does not require regex

Comment: Upvoting for the string method, there is no need for regex in something this simple, most languages have a library function for this

Answer (score 47):

Surprised that nobody has mentioned this which is my quick version for one-off scripts:

```
>>> x = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
>>> x.split('AAA')[1].split('ZZZ')[0]
'1234'
```

Comment: @user1810100 mentioned essentially that almost exactly 5 years to the day before you posted this...

Comment: Adding an `if s.find("ZZZ") > s.find("AAA"):` to it, avoids issues if 'ZZZ` isn't in the string, which would return `'1234uuijjk'`

Comment: @tzot's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917004/358532) with `partition` instead of `split` seems more robust (depending on your needs), as it returns an empty string if one of the substrings isn't found.

Answer (score 25):

you can do using just one line of code

```
>>> import re

>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,5}','gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk')

>>> ['1234']
```

result will receive list...

Answer (score 18):

```
import re
print re.search('AAA(.*?)ZZZ', 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk').group(1)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` - if there is no AAA, ZZZ in the string...

Answer (score 12):

You can use [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module for that:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(".*AAA(.*)ZZZ.*").match("gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk").groups()
('1234,)
```

Answer (score 12):

In python, extracting substring form string can be done using `findall` method in regular expression (`re`) module.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
>>> ss = re.findall('AAA(.+)ZZZ', s)
>>> print ss
['1234']
```

Answer (score 8):

```
text = 'I want to find a string between two substrings'
left = 'find a '
right = 'between two'

print(text[text.index(left)+len(left):text.index(right)])
```

Gives

```
string
```

Comment: If the text does not include the markers, throws a ValueError: substring not found exception. That is good,

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> s = '/tmp/10508.constantstring'
>>> s.split('/tmp/')[1].split('constantstring')[0].strip('.')
```

Answer (score 6):

> With sed it is possible to do something like this with a string:

`echo "$STRING" | sed -e "s|.*AAA\(.*\)ZZZ.*|\1|"`

> And this will give me 1234 as a result.

You could do the same  with `re.sub` function using the same regex.

```
>>> re.sub(r'.*AAA(.*)ZZZ.*', r'\1', 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk')
'1234'
```

In basic sed, capturing group are represented by `\(..\)`, but in python it was represented by `(..)`.

Answer (score 5):

> You can find first substring with this function in your code (by character index). Also, you can find what is after a substring.

```
def FindSubString(strText, strSubString, Offset=None):
    try:
        Start = strText.find(strSubString)
        if Start == -1:
            return -1 # Not Found
        else:
            if Offset == None:
                Result = strText[Start+len(strSubString):]
            elif Offset == 0:
                return Start
            else:
                AfterSubString = Start+len(strSubString)
                Result = strText[AfterSubString:AfterSubString + int(Offset)]
            return Result
    except:
        return -1

# Example:

Text = "Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!"
subText = "to"

print("Start of first substring in a text:")
start = FindSubString(Text, subText, 0)
print(start); print("")

print("Exact substring in a text:")
print(Text[start:start+len(subText)]); print("")

print("What is after substring \"%s\"?" %(subText))
print(FindSubString(Text, subText))

# Your answer:

Text = "gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk"
subText1 = "AAA"
subText2 = "ZZZ"

AfterText1 = FindSubString(Text, subText1, 0) + len(subText1)
BeforText2 = FindSubString(Text, subText2, 0) 

print("\nYour answer:\n%s" %(Text[AfterText1:BeforText2]))
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using PyParsing**

```py
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

s = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
rule = pp.nestedExpr('AAA', 'ZZZ')
for match in rule.searchString(s):
    print(match)
```

which yields:

`[['1234']]`

Answer (score 5):

One liner with Python 3.8 if `text` is guaranteed to contain the substring:

```
text[text.find(start:='AAA')+len(start):text.find('ZZZ')]
```

Comment: Does not work if the text does not contain the markers.

Comment: Similar solution by fernando-wittmann using text.index throws exception, allowing detection and forgiveness. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975532/2719980

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody will have to do the same thing that I did. I had to extract everything inside parenthesis in a line. For example, if I have a line like 'US president (Barack Obama) met with ...' and I want to get only 'Barack Obama' this is solution:

```
regex = '.*\((.*?)\).*'
matches = re.search(regex, line)
line = matches.group(1) + '\n'
```

I.e. you need to block parenthesis with `slash \` sign. Though it is a problem about more regular expressions that Python.

Also, in some cases you may see 'r' symbols before regex definition. If there is no r prefix, you need to use escape characters like in C. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix) is more discussion on that.

Answer (score 1):

also, you can find all combinations in the bellow function

```
s = 'Part 1. Part 2. Part 3 then more text'
def find_all_places(text,word):
    word_places = []
    i=0
    while True:
        word_place = text.find(word,i)
        i+=len(word)+word_place
        if i>=len(text):
            break
        if word_place<0:
            break
        word_places.append(word_place)
    return word_places
def find_all_combination(text,start,end):
    start_places = find_all_places(text,start)
    end_places = find_all_places(text,end)
    combination_list = []
    for start_place in start_places:
        for end_place in end_places:
            print(start_place)
            print(end_place)
            if start_place>=end_place:
                continue
            combination_list.append(text[start_place:end_place])
    return combination_list
find_all_combination(s,"Part","Part")
```

result:

```
['Part 1. ', 'Part 1. Part 2. ', 'Part 2. ']
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to look for multiple occurences.

```
content ="Prefix_helloworld_Suffix_stuff_Prefix_42_Suffix_andsoon"
strings = []
for c in content.split('Prefix_'):
    spos = c.find('_Suffix')
    if spos!=-1:
        strings.append( c[:spos])
print( strings )
```

Or more quickly :

```
strings = [ c[:c.find('_Suffix')] for c in content.split('Prefix_') if c.find('_Suffix')!=-1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without regex that also accounts for scenarios where the first substring contains the second substring. This function will only find a substring if the second marker is after the first marker.

```
def find_substring(string, start, end):
    len_until_end_of_first_match = string.find(start) + len(start)
    after_start = string[len_until_end_of_first_match:]
    return string[string.find(start) + len(start):len_until_end_of_first_match + after_start.find(end)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another way of doing it is using lists (supposing the substring you are looking for is made of numbers, only) :**

```
string = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
numbersList = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
output = []

for char in string:
    if char in numbersList: output.append(char)

print(f"output: {''.join(output)}")
### output: 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

> Typescript. Gets string in between two other strings.

Searches shortest string between prefixes and postfixes

prefixes - string / array of strings / null (means search from the start).

postfixes - string / array of strings / null (means search until the end).

```
public getStringInBetween(str: string, prefixes: string | string[] | null,
                          postfixes: string | string[] | null): string {

    if (typeof prefixes === 'string') {
        prefixes = [prefixes];
    }

    if (typeof postfixes === 'string') {
        postfixes = [postfixes];
    }

    if (!str || str.length < 1) {
        throw new Error(str + ' should contain ' + prefixes);
    }

    let start = prefixes === null ? { pos: 0, sub: '' } : this.indexOf(str, prefixes);
    const end = postfixes === null ? { pos: str.length, sub: '' } : this.indexOf(str, postfixes, start.pos + start.sub.length);

    let value = str.substring(start.pos + start.sub.length, end.pos);
    if (!value || value.length < 1) {
        throw new Error(str + ' should contain string in between ' + prefixes + ' and ' + postfixes);
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            start = this.indexOf(value, prefixes);
        } catch (e) {
            break;
        }
        value = value.substring(start.pos + start.sub.length);
        if (!value || value.length < 1) {
            throw new Error(str + ' should contain string in between ' + prefixes + ' and ' + postfixes);
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach could be the following:

```
string_to_search_in = 'could be anything'
start = string_to_search_in.find(str("sub string u want to identify"))
length = len("sub string u want to identify")
First_part_removed = string_to_search_in[start:]
end_coord = length
Extracted_substring=First_part_removed[:end_coord]
```

Comment: could you explain your code, so that it would be more helpful to the readers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the substrings exists and return empty string if they don't:

```
def substr_between(str_all, first_string, last_string):
    pos1 = str_all.find(first_string)
    if pos1 < 0:
        return ""
    pos1 += len(first_string)
    pos2 = str_all[pos1:].find(last_string)
    if pos2 < 0:
        return ""
    return str_all[pos1:pos1 + pos2]
```

Answer (score -1):

One liners that return other string if there was no match.
Edit: improved version uses `next` function, replace `"not-found"` with something else if needed:

```
import re
res = next( (m.group(1) for m in [re.search("AAA(.*?)ZZZ", "gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk" ),] if m), "not-found" )
```

My other method to do this, less optimal, uses regex 2nd time, still didn't found a shorter way:

```
import re
res = ( ( re.search("AAA(.*?)ZZZ", "gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk") or re.search("()","") ).group(1) )
```