# Check if string is upper, lower, or mixed case in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to classify a list of string in Python depending on whether they are upper case, lower case, or mixed case

How can I do this?

Comment: Consider the possibilities of (1) characters that are not letters and (2) letters that have no case at all.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

There are a number of "is methods" on strings. [`islower()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) and [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) should meet your needs:

```
>>> 'hello'.islower()
True

>>> [m for m in dir(str) if m.startswith('is')]
['isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper']
```

Here's an example of how to use those methods to classify a list of strings:

```
>>> words = ['The', 'quick', 'BROWN', 'Fox', 'jumped', 'OVER', 'the', 'Lazy', 'DOG']
>>> [word for word in words if word.islower()]
['quick', 'jumped', 'the']
>>> [word for word in words if word.isupper()]
['BROWN', 'OVER', 'DOG']
>>> [word for word in words if not word.islower() and not word.isupper()]
['The', 'Fox', 'Lazy']
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the short answer. But how do I classify words which are capitalized? For example: 'Mixed Word'. Seems the 3rd example fits all possible combinations of mixed words, example: "mIxEd WoRD"..

Comment: 'hello'.istitle()

Comment: @Stephen it's important to note that `istitle()` will only evaluate if the string is title case, *not* whether it's mixed case.  It will return false for a string such as `'The quick Brown Fox'`, as that's not title cased (but is obviously mixed case).

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a shoutout for using `re` module for this. Specially in the case of case sensitivity.

We use the option [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) while compiling the regex for use of in production environments with large amounts of data.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = ['isalnum','isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'ISALNUM', 'ISALPHA', 'ISDIGIT', 'ISLOWER', 'ISSPACE', 'ISTITLE', 'ISUPPER']
>>>
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile('is')
>>>
>>> [word for word in m if pattern.match(word)]
['isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper']
```

However try to always use the `in` operator for string comparison as detailed in this post

[faster-operation-re-match-or-str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find)

Also detailed in the one of the best books to start learning python with

[idiomatic-python](https://github.com/jeffknupp/blog/blob/master/content/2013-01-24-the-writing-idiomatic-python-ebook-is-finally-available.md)