# Convert titlecase words in the string to lowercase words

Tags: python, string, lowercase

I want to convert all the titlecase words *(words starting with uppercase character and having rest of the characters as lowercase)* in the string to the lowercase characters. For example, if my initial string is:

```
text = " ALL people ARE Great"
```

I want my resultant string to be:

```
 "ALL people ARE great"
```

I tried the following but it did not work

```
text = text.split()

for i in text:
        if i in [word for word in a if not word.islower() and not word.isupper()]:
            text[i]= text[i].lower()
```

I also checked related question [Check if string is upper, lower, or mixed case in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222855/check-if-string-is-upper-lower-or-mixed-case-in-python). I want to iterate over my dataframe and for each word that meet this criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your `transform` function

```
def transform(s):
    if len(s) == 1 and s.isupper():
        return s.lower()
    if s[0].isupper() and s[1:].islower():
        return s.lower()
    return s

text = " ALL people ARE Great"
final_text = " ".join([transform(word) for word in text.split()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.istitle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle) to check whether your word represents the titlecased string, i.e. whether first character of the word is uppercase and rest are lowercase.

For getting your desired result, you need to:

1. Convert your string to list of words using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
2. Do the transformation you need using [`str.istitle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle) and [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) *(I am using  **list comprehension** for iterating the list and for generating a new list of words in desired format)*
3. Join back the list to strings using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as:

For example:

```
>>> text = " ALL people ARE Great"

>>> ' '.join([word.lower() if word.istitle() else word for word in text.split()])
'ALL people ARE great'
```