# Search key phrases in text

Tags: python, nlp

I'm looking for a fast solution which allows me to find predefined phrases (1-5 words) in a (not big) text.

The phrases can be up to 1000. Suppose, the simple `find()` function is not a good solution.

Could you advise what should I use?
Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Why i don't want to use bruit force search:

- I believe, it is not fast enough.
- Text can have some inclusions in the phrases. I.e. phrase can be Bank America, but text has bank of America.
- Phrases can be a little bit changed - apostrophes, -s ending etc.

Comment: Is there any attempts ?

Comment: `Suppose, simple find function is not good solution`. If you have predefined phrases, why is a simple search not good enough? What have you already tried (and why is it not good enough)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your goal but you can easily find predefined prephrasses in text like that:

```
predefined_phrases = ["hello", "unicorns with a big mouth!", "Sweet donats"]
isnt_big_text = "A big mouse fly by unicorns with a big mouth! with hello wold."

for phrase in predefined_phrases:
    if phrase in isnt_big_text:
        print("Phrase '%s' found in text" % phrase)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I tried to found not bruit force solution and something faster

Comment: There was some research here in stackoverflow about search time python operators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find . "in" operator is fastest.