# How to not match whole word "king" to "king?"?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

How do I verify an exact word occurs in a string?

I need to account for cases when a word such as "king" has a question mark immediately following as in the example below.

**unigrams** this should be **False**

```
In [1]: answer = "king"
In [2]: context = "we run with the king? on sunday"
```

**n_grams** this should be **False**

```
In [1]: answer = "king tut"
In [2]: context = "we run with the king tut? on sunday"
```

**unigrams** this should be **True**

```
In [1]: answer = "king"
In [2]: context = "we run with the king on sunday"
```

**n_grams** this should be **True**

```
In [1]: answer = "king tut"
In [2]: context = "we run with the king tut on sunday"
```

As people mentioned, for the unigram case we can handle it by splitting the string into a list, but that doesn't work for n_grams.

After reading some posts, I think I should attempt to handle using a look behind, but I'm not sure.

Comment: All the problem is that you didn't clearly define what you call an *"exact word"*.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about a better theoretical definition, but a more concrete description of what is allowed before and after your needle. Nevertheless I praise your effort.

Comment: Should `"we tut with the king"` pass?

Comment: I think you should not have removed your attempt from the question.

Comment: The edit made a huge difference, but I think you still need to be more specific. For example, what should happen when `context` is `'king.'`? Ultimately, it sounds like regex is probably the right tool, but so far I doubt you need to employ anything more "exotic" than an exclusion set (such as `[^?]`).

Comment: @TemporalWolf `"we tut with the king"` should not pass.

Comment: What about `king? tut` ?

Comment: @mattyd2 I updated my answer, but given the new requirements a regex is probably a better answer... see Wiktor's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression like this:

```
reg_answer = re.compile(r"(?<!\S)" + re.escape(answer) + r"(?!\S)")
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/accowW)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind to ensure a match is preceded with whitespace or start of a string
- `re.escape(answer)` - a preprocessing step to make all special chars inside the search word be treated as literal chars
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead to ensure the match is followed with whitespace or end of string.

Answer (score 5):

```
return answer in context.split():

>>> answer in context.split()
False
```

You don't need a regex for this.

If you're looking for **keywords**:

```
all([ans in context.split() for ans in answer.split()])
```

will work with `"king tut"`, but that depends if you want to match strings like:

```
"we tut with the king"
```

If you don't, you still don't *need* a regex [(although you should probably use one)](https://repl.it/G8zH/0), given that you want to consider only whole terms (which are properly split, by default, via `.split()`):

```
def ngram_in(match, string):
    matches = match.split()
    if len(matches) == 1:
        return matches[0] in string.split()
    words = string.split()
    words_len = len(words)
    matches_len = len(matches)
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if index + matches_len > words_len:
            return False
        if word == matches[0]:
            for match_index, match in enumerate(matches):
                potential_match = True
                if words[index + match_index] != match:
                    potential_match = False
                    break
            if potential_match == True:
                return True
    return False
```

which is `O(n*m)` on a worst case string and about half as fast as a regex on normal strings.

```
>>> ngram_in("king", "was king tut a nice dude?")
True
>>> ngram_in("king", "was king? tut a nice dude?")
False
>>> ngram_in("king tut a", "was king tut a nice dude?")
True
>>> ngram_in("king tut a", "was king tut? a nice dude?")
False
>>> ngram_in("king tut a", "was king tut an nice dude?")
False
>>> ngram_in("king tut", "was king tut an nice dude?")
True
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @TemporalWolf. I'm going to update the post to address another case when this won't work.

Comment: The hundredth being: **what to do with all this free time**?

Comment: 100-99 = 1 problem = Perl

Answer (score 0):

Why not check:

```
if answer in context: do stuff
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find) for more details

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements. OP needs `'king'` to NOT be found in `'king?'`.