# Why is a compiled python regex slower?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find), the performance of regexes and Python's `in` operator were compared. However, the accepted answer uses `re.match`, which only matches the beginning of a string, and thus behaves completely different to `in`. Also, I wanted to see the performance gain of not recompiling the RE each time.

#### Surprisingly, I see that the pre-compiled version seems to be *slower*.

Any ideas why?

I am aware that there are quite a few other questions here that wonder about a similar issue. Most of them perform the way they do simply because they do not correctly reuse the compiled regex. If that is also my issue, please explain.

```
from timeit import timeit
import re

pattern = 'sed'
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod' \
       'tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'

compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

def find():
    assert text.find(pattern) > -1

def re_search():
    assert re.search(pattern, text)

def re_compiled():
    assert re.search(compiled_pattern, text)

def in_find():
    assert pattern in text

print('str.find     ', timeit(find))
print('re.search    ', timeit(re_search))
print('re (compiled)', timeit(re_compiled))
print('in           ', timeit(in_find))
```

Output:

```
str.find      0.36285957560356435
re.search     1.047689160564772
re (compiled) 1.575113873320307
in            0.1907925627077569
```

Comment: You should be doing `compiled_pattern.search(text)` not  `re.search(compiled_pattern, text)`

Comment: `compiled_pattern.search(text)` will be 3x faster. Still odd, though, that `re.search(compiled_pattern, text)` seems not to do the same.

Comment: Wow, you're right. So it's just a matter of `re.search` behaving poorly?

Comment: @tobias_k looking at the declaration, calling `re.search` simply does `return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)`. There's no check if the pattern is already compiled.

Comment: @asongtoruin But then `_compile` should do something like that, i.e. just return the input unmodified.

Comment: It *does*. Look at `re.py:294`. (Line number for Py3.6).

Comment: Maybe you should re-write the question to "Why is `re.search(pattern, text)` so much slower than `pattern.search(text)`?"

Comment: It's complicated. Sometimes it's faster, but it can be slower, depending on what's happening with the cache. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile) for some examples & discussion. Also take a look at the source code.

Comment: FWIW, that question I linked has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360900/4014959) by Python core developer, Raymond Hettinger, but it was added rather late, so it's not near the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this interesting question, I finished my quest to the python golden badge with it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Short answer

If you call [`compiled_pattern.search(text)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search) directly, it won't call `_compile` at all, it will be faster than [`re.search(pattern, text)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and much faster than `re.search(compiled_pattern, text)`.

This performance difference is due to `KeyError`s in cache and slow hash calculations for compiled patterns.

---

## `re` functions and `SRE_Pattern` methods

Any time a `re` function with a `pattern` as 1st argument (e.g. `re.search(pattern, string)` or `re.findall(pattern, string)`) is called, Python tries to compile the `pattern` first with `_compile` and then calls the corresponding method on the compiled pattern. For [example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/re.py#L179):

```
def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found."""
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

Note that `pattern` could be either a string or an already compiled pattern (an `SRE_Pattern` instance).

## _compile

Here's a compact version of [`_compile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/re.py#L281). I simply removed debug and flags check:

```
_cache = {}
_pattern_type = type(sre_compile.compile("", 0))
_MAXCACHE = 512

def _compile(pattern, flags):
    try:
        p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
        if loc is None or loc == _locale.setlocale(_locale.LC_CTYPE):
            return p
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if isinstance(pattern, _pattern_type):
        return pattern
    if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
        raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
        _cache.clear()
    loc = None
    _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags] = p, loc
    return p
```

### `_compile` with String pattern

When `_compile` is called with a string pattern, the compiled pattern is saved in `_cache` dict. Next time the same function is called (e.g. during the many `timeit` runs), `_compile` simply checks in `_cache` if this string has already been seen and returns the corresponding compiled pattern.

Using `ipdb` debugger in Spyder, it's easy to dive into `re.py` during execution.

```
import re

pattern = 'sed'
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod' \
       'tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'

compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

re.search(pattern, text)
re.search(pattern, text)
```

With a breakpoint at the second `re.search(pattern, text)`, it can be seen that the pair:

```
{(<class 'str'>, 'sed', 0): (re.compile('sed'), None)}
```

is saved in `_cache`. The compiled pattern is returned directly.

### `_compile` with compiled pattern

#### slow hash

What happens if `_compile` is called with an already compiled pattern?

First, `_compile` checks if the pattern is in `_cache`. To do so, it needs to calculate its hash. This calculation is much slower for a compiled pattern than for a string:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: pattern = "(?:a(?:b(?:b\\é|sorbed)|ccessing|gar|l(?:armists|ternation)|ngels|pparelled|u(?:daciousness's|gust|t(?:horitarianism's|obiographi
   ...: es)))|b(?:aden|e(?:nevolently|velled)|lackheads|ooze(?:'s|s))|c(?:a(?:esura|sts)|entenarians|h(?:eeriness's|lorination)|laudius|o(?:n(?:form
   ...: ist|vertor)|uriers)|reeks)|d(?:aze's|er(?:elicts|matologists)|i(?:nette|s(?:ciplinary|dain's))|u(?:chess's|shanbe))|e(?:lectrifying|x(?:ampl
   ...: ing|perts))|farmhands|g(?:r(?:eased|over)|uyed)|h(?:eft|oneycomb|u(?:g's|skies))|i(?:mperturbably|nterpreting)|j(?:a(?:guars|nitors)|odhpurs
   ...: 's)|kindnesses|m(?:itterrand's|onopoly's|umbled)|n(?:aivet\\é's|udity's)|p(?:a(?:n(?:els|icky|tomimed)|tios)|erpetuating|ointer|resentation|
   ...: yrite)|r(?:agtime|e(?:gret|stless))|s(?:aturated|c(?:apulae|urvy's|ylla's)|inne(?:rs|d)|m(?:irch's|udge's)|o(?:lecism's|utheast)|p(?:inals|o
   ...: onerism's)|tevedore|ung|weetest)|t(?:ailpipe's|easpoon|h(?:ermionic|ighbone)|i(?:biae|entsin)|osca's)|u(?:n(?:accented|earned)|pstaging)|v(?
   ...: :alerie's|onda)|w(?:hirl|ildfowl's|olfram)|zimmerman's)"

In [3]: compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)

In [4]: % timeit hash(pattern)
126 ns ± 0.358 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [5]: % timeit hash(compiled_pattern)
7.67 µs ± 21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`hash(compiled_pattern)` is 60 times slower than `hash(pattern)` here.

#### `KeyError`

When a `pattern` is unknown, `_cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]` fails with a `KeyError`.

The `KeyError` gets handled and ignored. Only then does `_compile` check if the pattern is already compiled. If it is, it gets returned, without being written in cache.

It means that the next time `_compile` is called with the same compiled pattern, it will calculate the useless, slow hash again, but will still fail with a `KeyError`.

Error handling is expensive, and I suppose that's the main reason why `re.search(compiled_pattern, text)` is slower than `re.search(pattern, text)`.

This weird behaviour might be a choice to speed up calls with string patterns, but it might have been a good idea to write a warning if `_compile` is called with an already compiled pattern.

Comment: I just ran into this performance problem, thanks for the excellent explanation! It seems like the type check (i.e. `if isinstance(pattern, _pattern_type)`) would be relatively fast, so I wonder why they don't just put that first in `_compile`