# A faster way to make a case-insensitive search of substring

Tags: python, string, lowercase

Is there a faster way to make a case-insensitive search for substring, other than the obvious

```
subtext.lower() in text.lower()
```

I work on small texts. Specifically, titles.

Comment: What's wrong with that method? Have you profiled your code and indicated that line is your bottleneck? If not, don't worry about premature optimization.

Comment: in this answer some different methods of performing this operation was profiled and it seems that this is fastests solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901653/5687152