# Get specific value of a string within a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have multiple strings defined as the following:

```
"Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='zeros', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01,l2=0.01), bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01,l2=0.01), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01,l2=0.01), kernel_constraint=max_norm(2.), bias_constraint=max_norm(2.), input_shape=(28,28,1))"
```

I want to extract the value of `kernel_size` in the string for which I tried the following thing:

```
match = re.search(i+'(.+?), (.+?) ',value)
```

where `i = 'kernel_size'` and and value is the string defined above.

When I run this, I get

```
<regex.Match object; span=(18, 38), match='kernel_size=(2, 2), '>
```

I also run the following command to get the value using the above match:

```
filters = match.group(1).split("=")[1].strip()
```

but I get this:

```
kernel_size (2
```

How can I get something like this:

```
kernel_size (2,2)
```

Comment: Maybe `re.search(r'kernel_size=\([^()]*\)', s).group()`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Ka6q7v).

Answer (score 1):

This expression might likely return that:

```
kernel_size\s*=\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)
```

with which we would just extract our desired digits using two capturing groups, then we would assemble them back to any format that we wish to output, such as `kernel_size (2,2)`.

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"kernel_size\s*=\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)"

test_str = ("Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1), padding='valid',\n"
    "Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=( 10  , 20 ), strides=(1,1), padding='valid',")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)

for match in matches:
    print('kernel_size ('+ match[0]+','+match[1]+')')
```

#### Output

```
kernel_size (2,2)
kernel_size (10,20)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6d9y2Z/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`re` is much slower than regular string operation in python (See [What's a faster operation, re.match/search or str.find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find) for example).

If you only need to get 1 value from the string, it is faster and probably simpler to use `string.find`

```
s = '<your string>'

pattern = 'kernel_size=('
p = s.find(pattern)
if p != -1:
    p += len(pattern)
    print('kernel_size (%s)' % s[p:s.find(')', p)])
```