# Extracting Data with Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around Python regular expressions to come up with a regular expression to extract specific values.

The page I am trying to parse has a number of productIds which appear in the following format

```
\"productId\":\"111111\"
```

I need to extract all the values, `111111` in this case.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on python regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: Is it that you are new to regex, python, or both?  Which part do you need help with?  What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract a substring from inside a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
t = "\"productId\":\"111111\""
m = re.match("\W*productId[^:]*:\D*(\d+)", t)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

meaning match non-word characters (`\W*`), then `productId` followed by non-column characters (`[^:]*`) and a `:`. Then match non-digits (`\D*`) and match and capture following digits (`(\d+)`).

**Output**

```
111111
```

Comment: Does this not need to be a raw string, or to have the backslashes escaped?

Answer (score 15):

something like this:

```
In [13]: s=r'\"productId\":\"111111\"'

In [14]: print s
\"productId\":\"111111\"

In [15]: import re

In [16]: re.findall(r'\d+', s)
Out[16]: ['111111']
```

Comment: I find this more Pythonic. :)

Answer (score 2):

The backslashes here might add to the confusion, because they are used as an escape character both by (non-raw) Python strings and by the regexp syntax.

This extracts the product ids from the format you posted:

```
re_prodId = re.compile(r'\\"productId\\":\\"([^"]+)\\"')
```

The raw string `r'...'` does away with one level of backslash escaping; the use of a single quote as the string delimiter does away with the need to escape double quotes; and finally the backslashe are doubled (only once) because of their special meaning in the regexp language.

You can use the regexp object's `findall()` method to find all matches in some text:

```
re_prodId.findall(text_to_search)
```

This will return a list of all product ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 :\\"(\d*)\\"
```

Give more examples of your data if this doesn't do what you want.