# how to extract a multiple substring from inside a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I refer to the question [how to extract a substring from inside a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python) and have further question.

What if my string is something like:

`gfgfdAAA1234ZZZsddgAAA4567ZZZuijjk`

I want to extract `1234` and `4567`, is it stored as a list?

Comment: Use `re.findall`: `re.findall('AAA(.+?)ZZZ', text)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
re.findall('\d+','gfgfdAAA1234ZZZsddgAAA4567ZZZuijjk')
['1234', '4567']
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm not understanding you correctly, but you can certainly extract these substrings as a `list`, though you do it slightly differently:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZsddgAAA4567ZZZuijjk'
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9]{4}', text)
['1234', '4567']
```