# How to get url route, python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

For example i have an URL

```
http://example.com/myscript/myaction?param1=something
```

Under *myscript* alias I have my python cgi script and i want to get the route after myscript as a string. In this case route should be 'myaction'. How to do that with python + pure CGI + apache

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression, much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python) (this question also includes other solutions to the same problem)

```
import re
```

Take your URL

```
url = 'http://example.com/myscript/myaction?param1=something'
```

Then extract everything between '*myscript/*' and '*?*'

```
m = re.search('myscript/(.+?)\?', url)
```

Then use it

```
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
    print found
```

Comment: and how to do it if address either can end with a question or with a new line

.../myscript/myaction
or even can end with /
.../myscript/myaction/