# Can't get re.search() to work in Python

Tags: python, regex, string-parsing

I have a string of type "*animal* cat dog" and I am trying to extract *animal* from it.

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667014/4971456), I tried using re.search (and also re.match later), however that didn't produce the result I expected. The if statement would go through but groups() would be empty.

The code I had:

```
string = "fox cat dog"
regex = "\S+ cat dog\s*"
m = re.search(regex, string)    
if m:
    temp = m.group(1)
```

I tried printing out m and m.groups() and they had the following values:

```
m: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000002009A920>  
m.groups(): ()
```

I found a way around the problem by using substrings and .find() but I am very curious what was wrong with my original code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is no defined group in your pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add a parenthesis to the group you want. Like so:

```
string = "fox cat dog"
regex = "(\S+) cat dog\s*"
#       ~~~~~~Note the parenthesis there
m = re.search(regex, string)    
if m:
    temp = m.group(1)
```

You may want to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more information:

> (...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
>   and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
>   can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
>   later in the string with the \number special sequence, described
>   below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use `\(` or `\)`, or enclose them
>   inside a character class: [(] [)].