# Extract substring between specific characters

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings like:

```
\i{}Agrostis\i0{} <L.>
```

I would like to get rid of the '\i{}', '\io{}' characters, so that I could get just:

```
Agrostis <L.>
```

I've tried the following code (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python)):

```
m = re.search('\i{}(.+?)\i0', item_name)
if m:
   name = m.group(1).strip('\\')
else:
   name = item_name
```

It works in part, because when I run it I get just:

```
Agrostis
```

without the

```
<L.>
```

part (which I want to keep).

Any hints?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Are you sure the `\i{}` and `\io{}` substrings occur exactly once in the string, with the first always coming before the second?

Comment: Yes, they all have the very same format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `s.replace('\i{}', '')` and `s.replace('\io{}', '')`

Answer (score 1):

You ca do this in different ways.

The simplest one is to use str.replace

```
s = '''\i{}Agrostis\i0{} <L.>'''
s2 = s.replace('''\i{}''', '').replace('''\i0{}''', '')
```

Another way is to use `re.sub()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```
In [34]: import re

In [35]: s = "\i{}Agrostis\i0{} <L.>"

In [36]: re.sub(r'\\i\d*{}', '', s)
Out[36]: 'Agrostis <L.>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *character class* along with `re.sub()`

```
import re
regex = r'\\i[\d{}]+'
string = "\i{}Agrostis\i0{} <L.>"

string = re.sub(regex, '', string)
print string
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/6Nwctc).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `s.replace('\i{}', '')` and `s.replace('\io{}', '')`, as Julien said, or, continuing with the regex approach, change your pattern to:

`re.search('\i{}(.+?)\i0(.++)', item_name)`

And use `m.group(1).strip('\\') + m.group(2).strip('\\')` as the result.