# extract a pattern number from url mysql or python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have a bunch url that has a string either has

```
hotel+4 digit number: hotel1234 
or slash+4digit.html: /1234.html
```

Is there a regex to extract 4 digit number like 1234 either use python or mysql?

I'm thinking  'hotel'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],sth like this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}$'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}$';
```

Comment: would you know how to regexp '/1234.html' ? this exact pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a stackoverflow.com link that might be useful showing
[how to extract a substring from inside a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python)

Unfortunately, MySQL regexp simply returns true if the string exists.  I have found substring_index useful if you know the text surrounding the target...

```
select case when ColumnName like 'hotel____' then substring_index(ColumnName,'hotel',-1)
            when ColumnName like '/____.html' then substring_index(substring_index(ColumnName,'/',-1),'.html',1)
            else ColumnName
             end digit_extraction
  from TableName
 where ...;
```

The case statement above isn't necessary because of the way substring_index works (by returning the entire string if the search string isn't found).

```
select substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(ColumnName,'hotel',-1),'/',-1),'.html',1)
  from TableName
 where ...;
```