# Extracting data from javascript var inside <script> with python

Tags: javascript, python, json, apache-nifi

I'm new with python, BeautifulSoup and other but
I want to extract json data which are inside a javascript variable in the "script" tag of a web site.

Here is my code for now :

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests
url = 'myUrl'
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r"var hours = .")
script = soup.find("script",text=pattern)
print(script)
```

for now I can extract the data with the format like :

```
<script>
var hours = [{...dataIwant...}];
<\script>
```

But I only want the data without "script" or "var hours =". I want to change it in json and put it in apache nifi.

I have tried pretty much everything I have found here and on google. But most of the time when I try to extract the variable and change it to json format I have "None" or other errors.

So if you have some tips to help me get the data in json format it would be great !

Thank you !

Comment: You could capture it in a group [`var hours = (.+),`](https://regex101.com/r/q2CAZe/1)

Comment: in my pattern = re.compile ? or a re.search after the soup.find ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "script" is a string after you used soup.find()
you could use regular expression to get the part you need.
Something like this could work.

```
m = re.search('var hours = (.+)[,;]{1}', script)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
```

See: [How to extract a substring from inside a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python#4667014)

Comment: Hmm I think I have already tried that, which returned "None". But I will try it again as soon as possible !

Comment: Almost this, Thank you ! 
It extract the Array but not the data after it like 'latitude or longitude'. But I will find a way to do it.
After that I just need to parse the Json and it will be good.

Thank you very much !