# How to extract a dynamic substring from a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, html, loops

I have a list of strings I scraped off the internet and I'm looking to extract their 'href':

```
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/red-wine">Red Wine</a></li>
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/white-wine">White Wine</a></li>
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/rose-wine">Rosé Wine</a></li>
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/fine-wine">Fine Wine</a></li>
```

For example, I'm looking to loop through the list and dynamically extract

> /red-wine

from

```
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/red-wine">Red Wine</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: use the reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python
This might be what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the required text using Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import *
data = '\
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/red-wine">Red Wine</a></li>\
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/white-wine">White Wine</a></li>\
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/rose-wine">Rosé Wine</a></li>\
<li class="subnav__item"><a class="subnav__link " href="/fine-wine">Fine Wine</a></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

lis = soup.findAll('a')
for li in lis:
    print(li['href'])
```

> ```
> /red-wine
> /white-wine
> /rose-wine
> /fine-wine
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lxml` for this. Something like this:

```
from lxml import html
import request

response = request.get('<your url>')
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
href = tree.xpath('//a[@class="subnav__item"]/@href')
```

This should get you all the `href` in from the class `"subnav__item"`