# Rename ReadGeo nodes by Alembic SceneGraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, nuke, alembic-format

I have 7 shots with 2 or 3 Alembic files in each and around 20 geometries per Alembic.

As I need to export my complete 3D scene in a new Alembic, I need to rename all of the `ReadGeo` nodes to be easily readable in other software (like Maya).

For this, I want to give the geometry name from the Alembic `Scenegraph` to the `ReadGeo` but I don't see how to found `Geo` name with Python. I have started with this code:

```
def AlembicRename():
    for s in nuke.allNodes("ReadGeo2"):
        GeoName = # don't know how to find this
        s['name'].setValue(GeoName)

AlembicRename()
```

Any idea how I can find the `Geometry` Name?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with

```
myReadGeoNode['scene_view'].getSelectedItems()
```

Answer (score 1):

To access ABC's Scenegraph's hierarchy in NUKE, you should try this code:

```
import nuke

# 'ReadGeo2' – node's class 
nuke.createNode('ReadGeo2', 'file { /Users/swift/Desktop/scene.abc }') 

def alembicRename():
    # 'ReadGeo18' – node's name in graph 
    for s in nuke.allNodes('ReadGeo18'):
        sceneView = s['scene_view']
        hierarchy = sceneView.getAllItems()
        print hierarchy

alembicRename()

# Result: ['/root/polySphere/polySphereShape']
```

To find out how to extract a substring from inside a string using Python read [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python). After extracting process you can assign (`polySphere`, for example) name to your `ReadGeo` node. And do not forget: there is a Python's list containing only zero index.

```
s['name'].setValue(hierarchy[0])
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i have founded the same principle but with myReadGeoNode['scene_view'].getSelectedItems(), then i can isolate the wanted geometry

Comment: hi, yes because it's not the right name, I needed to have only selected geo name so the command i was looking for is getSelectedItems() then separate each  / to have the real geo name in the last entry

Comment: In case you have several groups of geometry inside compound multilayered hierarchy, `.getAllItems()` nuke method + `substring extraction` operation are more robust and reliable than just `.getSelectedItems()` method.

Comment: hi, can you explain why please ?

Comment: Hi)) You might have a compound geometry, not mono. So, definite layer in DAG's hierarchy has all the parts of your object but `.getSelectedItems()` may not select all the desired parts of geometry. In simple cases `.getSelectedItems()` method is quite useful.

Comment: That's why I prefer using `.getAllItems()` and `substring extraction`, not the `.getSelectedItems()`.