# How to create and delete a user from Jenkins through REST API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Are there any REST APIs exposed by Jenkins to create and delete a user?

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051914/5995009) there's no way to easily do it via REST API. I'm currently facing the same problem and came up with some kind of web scraping. This is required as Jenkins eventually expects a Jenkins-Crumb to be supplied via the user deletion POST request.

Whenever you want to **People > Click on User Id > Delete** a user, you have to confirm that you really want to delete that user. Besides that obvious **Yes** button there are some hidden form fields where one of those is named **Jenkins-Crumb**. When you click the **Yes** button the value of that field is sent with the */doDelete* POST request.

The solution I came up with is reading the Jenkins-Crumb after GETting `https://<your-jenkins-url>/user/<username-to-delete>/delete` and then do a POST request to `https://<your-jenkins-url>/user/<username-to-delete>/doDelete` with the Jenkins-Crumb supplied as form data. While the Jenkins-Crumb form field is populated via JavaScript, there's no need to execute the JavaScript as the script is directly included as `<script>crumb.init("Jenkins-Crumb", "jenkins-crumb-value");</script>` into the HTML source where it can be [matched via RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667014/5995009).

In Python this could look like

```py
import re, requests, sys

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = (ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_APIKEY_OR_PASSWORD)
    url = "https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/user/USER_TO_DELETE/delete"
    response = s.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        sys.exit("HTTP error {} while accessing Jenkins at {}. Exiting.".format(response.status_code, url))

    re_match = re.search(r'<script>crumb\.init\("Jenkins-Crumb", "(\w+)"\);<\/script>', response.text)
    if not re_match:
        sys.exit("Couldn't get required Jenkins-Crumb. Exiting.")

    jenkins_crumb = re_match.group(1)

    url = "https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/user/USER_TO_DELETE/doDelete"
    data = { "Jenkins-Crumb": jenkins_crumb }
    response = s.post(url, params=data)

    if not response.ok:
        sys.exit("Couldn't delete user")

    s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently no.  Many pages, but not all pages in Jenkins expose json (that can be consumed) by adding `api/json` to the end of the Jenkins URL.

The Security related pages in Jenkins are not currently part of the REST API.

That said yesterday (as I write this answer) the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) has released version [2.90](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin#RoleStrategyPlugin-Version2.9.0(Aug27,2018)) that adds some REST API capability.

Maybe this is the start of more.