# Extract all numbers in brackets with Python

Tags: python, find, brackets

i have a string looking like this:

```
s = "asd[123]348dsdk[45]sdhj71[6789]sdfh"
```

i need an other string that contains the numbers in brackets like this:

```
s_filter = "123 45 6789"
```

Sorry for not posting my own ideas!
i tried to use this:

```
s = "asd[123]348dsdk[45]sdhj71[6789]sdfh"
s_filter = s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]

result: s_filter = "123"
```

But it only gives me the first numbers.

Any ideas?

Best,
Hans

Comment: please make an attempt and share your attempt before asking, SO is not a coding service

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can do that:

```
s = "asd[123]348dsdk[45]sdhj71[6789]sdfh"
import re
s_filter  = ' '.join(re.findall(r"\[(\d+)\]",s)))

print(s_filter)
```

Output:

```
123 45 6789
```

Pattern explained:

```
\[         \]   are the literal square brackets
    (\d+?)      as as few numbers inside them as capture group
```

`re.findall` finds them all and `' '.join(iterable)`combines them back into a string.

Comment: I keep meaning to read up on that module, just too lazy I guess.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Simple if/elif statment will do it:

```
s = "asd[123]348dsdk[45]sdhj71[6789]sdfh"

s_filter = ""
x = False
for i in s:
    if i == "[": x = True
    elif i == "]": x = False
    elif x: s_filter += i

print(s_filter)
```

Output:

```
123456789
```