# Substring between known two markers extraction with problem markers

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

@miernic [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers?answertab=votes#tab-top) long ago how do you extract an arbitrary string which is located between two known markers in another string.

My problem is that the two markers include Regular Expression's meta characters. Specifically, I need to extract **ABCD** from the string **('ABCD',)**, parenthesis, single quote and comma, all included in the source string. The extracted string itself might include single and double quotes, dots, parenthesis, and white space. The makers are always **('** and **',)**.

I tried to use r' strings and lots of escape characters and nothing works.

Pleeeease....

Comment: Just use `r"\('(.+?)',\)"` in `re.findall`

Comment: `I tried to use r' strings and lots of escape characters and nothing works.`, what have you tried?

Comment: @Toto: I tried ```r"('(.+?)')```. The suggestion of @anubhava did work. Thank you. My (erroneous) assumption was that r-strings and escape characters are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex with `"` as regex delimiter:

```
r"\('(.+?)',\)"
```

Use above regex in `re.findall` so that you get only captured group returned from it.