# Printing an extracted substring using regex results in "<built-in function id>"

Tags: python, regex, string

I was looking up how to extract a substring from a strong and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers) posted question on StackOverflow. This is the set of lists I want to extract just the number from (ie extract '39' from 'ID: 39'):

```
['Atalanta ', 'ID: 39) ']
['RB Leipzig ', 'ID: 112172) ']
['Manchester United ', 'ID: 11) ']
['Borussia Dortmund ', 'ID: 22) ']
['Liverpool ', 'ID: 9) ']
['Tottenham Hotspur ', 'ID: 18) ']
```

And the code I have to do so is based on the above linked post:

```
id_uncleaned = name_id_list[1]

found = re.search('\(ID: (\d*)\)', id_uncleaned)

if found:
    id = found.group(1)

print(id)
```

But this is returning a `<built-in function id>` when I try to print it. Why is that and how can I just get the numbers from '39', etc. instead?

Comment: Try this expression: `found = re.search('ID: (\d*)\)', id_uncleaned)`

Comment: @ferhen, Thank you! That solved it.

Comment: @MenglongLi `id` it is not a [python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Answer (score 2):

id is an internal function of Python. If found is not set to a value then the line `id = found.group(1)` doesn't happen, and so when you print(id) you get its original value.
Avoid using id as a name for variables and it will be clearer.