# Python String Extract between </div> and </td>

Tags: python, python-re

I am scraping a website using python and BeautifulSoup. I was able to find all the tds on the page with the command:

```
data = soup.find_all('td')
```

Then I find the first individual td that I need to use:

```
td = data[19]
```

If I print this td the output is:

```
<td data-geoid="0617568" data-isnumeric="1" data-srcnote="true" data-value="18.8">
<span data-title="Culver City city, California"></span><div class="qf-sourcenote">
<span></span><a title="Source: 2018 American Community Survey (ACS), 5-year estimates. Estimates are not comparable to other geographic levels due to methodology differences that may exist between different data sources."></a>
</div>18.8%</td>
```

Now I want to extract the data that is between the end of the div and the end of the td, so the 18.8%. I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers) to try to extract it with the following code:

```
m = re.search('</div>(.+?)</td>', td)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alfie/PycharmProjects/474scrape/srape.py", line 18, in <module>
    m = re.search('</div>(.+?)</td>', td)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I think the problem is with escape characters or something similar that are in the markers I am using. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`td` is probably not of type `str`.

If `td` were of type `str`, the code should work just fine.

```
import re

td = """
<td data-geoid="0617568" data-isnumeric="1" data-srcnote="true" data-value="18.8">
<span data-title="Culver City city, California"></span><div class="qf-sourcenote">
<span></span><a title="Source: 2018 American Community Survey (ACS), 5-year estimates. Estimates are not comparable to other geographic levels due to methodology differences that may exist between different data sources."></a>
</div>18.8%</td>
"""

m = re.search(r'</div>(.+?)</td>', td)
print(m.group(1))
# 18.8%
```

Try replacing

```
m = re.search(r'</div>(.+?)</td>', td)
```

with

```
m = re.search(r'</div>(.+?)</td>', str(td))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing pattern as a raw string.

```
m = re.search(r'</div>(.+?)</td>', td)
```

If this doesn't work, check type of td and if it's not a string, then convert it to string and then pass to the function.