# Extract Substring which is between String

Tags: python, python-re

Suppose I have a string "Amar Kulkarni is a Good Boy."

I just want the string between "is an" and "."(a Dot)

I have tried using

```
    import re
    finalresults = re.search('is an(.+?).', results)
    print(finalresults)
```

But, it doesn't seems to work out.
Help Please.

Comment: In regexes, the `.` means "any character".  If you want a literal `.` character, you need to escape it: `\.`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Comment: In this particular example, _nothing_ is between "is an" and ".". Your string says "is _a_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import re

text = 'a is an b. kk is an c.c.'
try:
     found = re.search('is an(.+?)\.', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
     found = '' 

print(found)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir !!! Your Suggestion helped me out . Thank  You Again!!!

Comment: My pleasure! So glad it helps. All the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `.` using `\`, Try :

```
finalresults = re.search('is an(.+?)\.', results)
```

Note that `.` is always a wildcard until you escape it.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression uses Positive lookbehind and Positive lookahead to match the string.

```
r'(?<=is an).*?(?=\.)'
```

**Note:** this will not match `is an` and `.`

https://regex101.com/r/KGiGNQ/1