# How to extract a required text from a line of text using Python?

Tags: python

[Available formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwwH.jpg)

Since I am a newbie to the Python world can anyone help me with the below scenario :

I have texts/descriptions from which I need to extract the word "PO" and the digits following it using Python.

I tried to extracting digits, but without success.

The formats are as below :

> Additional Funnel Ireland (50% Deposit) - PO 12345
> Monthly Retainer (PO00011223)
> PO0000054321: 3 months: August, September, October
> Monthly Retainer PYB (PO 11236)
> Additional Funnel Czech Republic (50%) - PO is 78901

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Comment: What is the logic supposed to be? Digits at the end? "PO" followed by anything followed by digits? The rules are unclear.

Comment: You can try regex : 
match = re.match("^(.*)(PO)(.*?)(\d+)$", line)
print(match.group(2), match.group(4))

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - i want the "PO" with all the digits wherever it is in the text. i hope i made my query clear now.. i have given for the available formats as well..

Comment: @ShivamSeth will this work with all the formats i have included in my question?

Comment: yes, I tried with most of the pattern but only integers at end  not float, This is basic code, You need to loop though each line or enable MultiLine flag of regex, you can include basic None check after pattern match, in case if not match, I could have posted entire code but your question is not accepting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data always looks like you posted, e.g.:

> Additional Funnel Ireland (50% Deposit) - PO 12345
> Monthly Retainer (PO00011223)
> PO0000054321: 3 months: August, September, October
> Monthly Retainer PYB (PO 11236)
> Additional Funnel Czech Republic (50%) - PO is 78901

You can use regular expressions to extract your string,

```
import re
res = ''.join(re.search('(PO)[\sA-Za-z]*(\d+)', s).groups())
```

According to your previous post, the old solution was

```
s = "Additional Funnel Ireland(50% deposit) - PO 12345"
splitted = s.split(' - ')[-1].split()
res = splitted[0]+splitted[-1]
```

This first extracts the last part (by splitting using `-`) to get the part where you are interested in. Then you split again (by  ) to finally get rid of possible intermediate text.

Comment: pls check https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwwH.jpg

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Please edit your questions such that all possible strings are included.

Comment: i have included the image for available formats. :)

Comment: @AbhishekMishra I guess it is hard to copy the data from your image for testing...

Comment: I have edited the question... included the available formats as text...

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Ok, thanks. I adapted my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same, you can split the whole string by the spaces and grab the last en 2 but last position:

```
txt = "Additional funnel Czech Rep(50%) - PO is 12345"
splt = txt.split()

print(splt[-3], splt[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering PO 12345 is a string, you can select the 8 last characters of this string using `[-8:]`.

Example :

```py
a = 'code is 1234'
print(a[-4:])
```

Output gives `'1234'`.

Answer (score 0):

***the following is the easiest way to extract the data***

**logic->**
use string.find method to look for the index of PO in the string.
lets assume x is the index of PO

extracted_string=PO[x:]

then replace the **is** with no space.

**code->**

```
txt = "Additional funnel Czech Rep(50%) - PO is 12345"
index=txt.find("PO")
extracted_string=txt[index:]
print(extracted_string.replace(" is ","")
```

**Output**

```
PO12345
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwwH.jpg can you please check this link for the formats i have and help me out please

Comment: do all the strings end with 5 or they vary?

Comment: the numbers will vary

Comment: I have included he available formats in the question as text. you can pickup from there