# how to extract specific string from api response in python?

Tags: python, split

how to extract "e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076"  from the below api response in python   ?

{"message": "Rendition service output e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076/ae8f5aae-4d6a-5a17-9f95-d918634a668c has been created successfully."}

Comment: What did you try ? Have converted json or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the API response is fixed, you can use regex to extract your data.

```
import regex

message = "Rendition service output e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076/ae8f5aae-4d6a-5a17-9f95-d918634a668c has been created successfully."

m = regex.search('output (.+?)/', message)

if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    # prints e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076
```

If you don't want to use regex you could do:

```
start = message.find('output ') + len('output ') # To get the index of the character behind this string
end = message.find('/', start)
print(message[start:end])
# prints e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076
```

Found the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the message follows the same format always, there are several ways:
First I save the message on a variable `d` so I can work with it:

```
d = {"message": "Rendition service output e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076/ae8f5aae-4d6a-5a17-9f95-d918634a668c has been created successfully."}
```

Solution 1:

```
d['message'][25:].split('/')[0]
'e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076'
```

Solution 2 (I like this one more):

```
d['message'].split(' ')[3].split('/')[0]
'e2f64fd6-13aa-5c6c-932a-c366a4f56076'
```