# Clicking on the correct option from a given list of options in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I am trying to give input to the 'Currency I have' text box. This input is in the variable 'currency'. After I give the input in the text box, it displays a number of options. I want to do a case insensitive match on the 3 letter currency code I enter and the options the text box displays in the drop-down, and select the correct one.
The page I am testing: https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates

```
currency = currency_list.loc[i,'currency']
    print(f'\nFETCHING DATA FOR : {currency}')
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    
    #input our currency in "currency I have" text-box
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#havePicker > div'))).click()
    currency_have = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#havePicker > div > input')))
    
    try:
        currency_have.clear() 
    except:
        pass
    
    currency_have.send_keys(currency)
    options = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#havePicker > div > ul li')))
    
    div_tags = [li_tags.find_elements_by_tag_name('div') for li_tags in options]
        
    for div_tag in div_tags:
        test = div_tag[1]
        if (test.text.casefold()) == (currency.casefold()):
            return test
        else:
            continue
```

The return statement in my code is incorrect. How do I proceed further to achieve my goal?

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking many questions in one. What is the main problem?

Comment: @vitaliis I'm sorry. I edited the question. I hope I'm able to explain my problem in a better language.

Comment: Check my answer, I think it will help you. Also, it may be helpful if someone else decides to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to wait for dropdown result, the order of your actions should be the following:

- Clear "Currency I have" dropdown
- Click it (not completely sure if this action is required, test it)
- Wait for all values
- Send value ("Australian dollar") # not AUD as there is also Saudi Riyal in search results

This part of code should look like below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#havePicker > div'))).click()
currency_have = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#havePicker > div > input')))

currency_have.clear()
currency_have.click()

options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#havePicker > div > ul li')))
currency_have.send_keys("Australian dollar")
```

Please note that you have two results on `AUD`. That's why I used the full currency name. If you want to use just aud, use `split()` Check here how to use it [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)
Then improve your for loop.