# How to save these coordinates to variables in python

Tags: python

I have this string which is a response from 2captcha

```
{'captchaId': '69775358180', 'code':
'coordinates:x=100,y=285;x=147,y=299;x=226,y=316;x=262,y=131'}
```

how can I extract each x,y coordinate  and save them to variable? I've played around with regex but cant quite figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like a dictionary, not a string

Comment: Are you sure that's a string? Can you provide the ``repr`` of it? Or are you asking just about the ``'coordinates:...'`` part?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. Good catch

Comment: What do you mean "save then to variable"? Do you want a list of integers? A list of x, y tuples? A bunch of individual variables (probably not a good idea)? Something else? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem statement isn't clear yet. if you are talking about "'coordinates:x=100,y=285;x=147,y=299;x=226,y=316;x=262,y=131'" as string because in question it looks like dictionary to me. Also, This problem is related to only this particular response string or you need to write a code that needs to be written in a general manner for any values having the different values for x,y coordinates in the same pattern string.

Comment: I found something similar to your problem. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers" You can try this. It might solve your issue.

Comment: Im trying to save each x,y coordinate the response gives to a variable( if thats the correct thing , im new to python) so i can use theses coordinates to click on a certain place on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a code to get the x and y coordinates and store them in their own list:

```
data ={'captchaId': '69775358180', 'code': 'coordinates:x=100,y=285;x=147,y=299;x=226,y=316;x=262,y=131'}

#this gets the 'x=100,y=285;x=147,y=299;x=226,y=316;x=262,y=131'
coordinates = data['code'].split(':')[1].split(';')

x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []

for pair in coordinates:
  xy = pair.split(',')
  x_coordinates.append(xy[0][2:])
  y_coordinates.append(xy[1][2:])

print(x_coordinates) # ['100', '147', '226', '262']
print(y_coordinates) # ['285', '299', '316', '131']
```

If you need a single x or y coordinate just access them using the index of the list.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a dictionary you could use this code to create a list of the co-ordinates as tuples.

```py
data = {'captchaId': '69775358180', 'code':
'coordinates:x=100,y=285;x=147,y=299;x=226,y=316;x=262,y=131'}

coords =[(xy.split(',')[0][2:],xy.split(',')[1][2:] ) for xy in data['code'][12:].split(";")]

print(coords)
```

```
[('100', '285'), ('147', '299'), ('226', '316'), ('262', '131')]
```

If you wanted numeric co-ordinates:

```py
coords =[(int(xy.split(',')[0][2:]),int(xy.split(',')[1][3:]) ) for xy in data['code'][12:].split(";")]
```

```
[(100, 85), (147, 99), (226, 16), (262, 31)]
```

Comment: brilliant , thanks. Is there anyway to save the coords as a single ? as in [(100), (85) , (147) , (99) etc etc

so when i use print(coords[0]) it will be 100 and not 100,85

Comment: You can use `coords[0][0]` to get the first x co-ordinate and `coords[0][1]` to get the first y co-ordinate and so on. Also, having the co-ordinates as tuples in a list could actually be useful depending on your next step.