# How to find specific string while using lists?

Tags: python, filereader, cpython

I was making my simple `filereader` using python and cpython. But, I realized that it displayed an error that is `TypeError: 'list' object has to attribute to find`. Is there any way to find a specific character inside a list and return it? Thanks :D

### Main python module

```py
import io;

class AdvancedReader(object):
  def __init__(self, file, mode=None, buffering=None, encoding=None, *args):
    data_file = io.open(file, mode=mode, buffering=buffering, encoding=encoding)
    striped_list = [lines.strip() for lines in (data_file.readlines())]
    if any(map('['.startswith and ']'.endswith, striped_list)):
       _starter = ([for item in striped_list.startswith('[')])
       # stater = striped_list.filter('[', ‘]’) #Removing brackets
```

### Simple using for class

```py
AdvancedReader('settings.def', mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding='utf-8')
```

This is the atributte error that displayed inside my class...

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main. py"
, line 13, in «module>
AdvancedReader("settinas.def".mode='r', buffering=-1. encoding='utf-g)
File "main.py", line 9, in
init
print(striped list. find(r))
AttributeError: list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is the settings.def file, its practically a new type of storage/file systax for python only.

```
[SYSTEM] // Begining acronym
 start: os.system('echo hello world')
[/SYSTEM] // Ending acronym
```

Comment: Have you copied the error message correctly? Please include the whole traceback (and the line that produces the error)

Comment: And does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, Here is more information

Comment: Did the link to another question help?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych It gave the same error, but a return as none

Comment: Your traceback mentions line 9 in main.py, but you have not provided the code for that. Can you make a minimal complete example that produces your error?

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers).