# Pyspark: Find a substring delimited by multiple characters

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im trying to extract a substring that is delimited by other substrings in Pyspark. In the example text, the desired string would be THEVALUEINEED, which is delimited by "meterValue=" and by "{". This is important since there are several values in the string i'm trying to parse following the same format: "field= THEVALUE {". Therefore I need to specify the initial delimiting string and the string that comes after the desired value (closing string).

```
string = request={meterValue=THEVALUEINEED{sampledVaLue=ANOTHERVALUE...
```

I tried solving it with re.search [(See here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers) but I cannot make it run in PySpark when I pass a column of strings as the input string.

"message" is the column that contains the various strings in each row, therefore I want to parse the values and paste them on a new column (newColumn).

```
 df = df.withColumn("newColumn", re.search('meterValue={(.*)}', F.col("message")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |message                                            |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{meterValue=THEVALUEINEED{sampledVaLue=ANOTHERVALUE|
|2  |{meterValue=THEVALUEINEED{sampledVaLue=ANOTHERVALUE|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Just do that, find the words between `meterValue=` and `{`

```
df.withColumn('name', regexp_extract('message', '(?<=meterValue=)(\w+)(?=\{)',1)).show()
```

output

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|id |message                                            |name         |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|1  |{meterValue=THEVALUEINEED{sampledVaLue=ANOTHERVALUE|THEVALUEINEED|
|2  |{meterValue=THEVALUEINEED{sampledVaLue=ANOTHERVALUE|THEVALUEINEED|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```