# How I read a word after the @ symbol

Tags: python, stringreader

I'm having a problem. I need to create the @everyone_or_person feature. A bit like discord. But I'll have to be able to read the word after the @ and stop reading when there is a ("SPACE"/"_") and check for that word in the list. I've appended a simple version as an example. I knew it would not work but I couldn't think of anything else.

```
input = input("input: ")
value = input.find("@")

output = input.partition("@")[0]
print(str(output))
```

I've tried to look up how to do it but to no avail.

Comment: `input.split('@')[1].split()[0]`. Or better use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: input.split('@')[1] <br>
This will split the string into a list with the seperator @ and you can read the string after the @ with the [1].

Comment: Aaand does this answer your question? [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Comment: Don't call your variable `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `split`:

```
test = "Some input with @your_desired_value in it"
result = test.split("@")[1].split(" ")[0]
print(result)
```

this splits your text at the @, takes the entire string after the @, splits again at the first space, and takes the string before that.