# Regular expression to filter list of strings matching a pattern

Tags: python, regex, list, subset

I use R a lot more and it is easier for me to do it in R:

```
> test <- c('bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa')
> test[grepl("^x",test)]
[1] "xzz" "xaa"
```

But how to do it in python if `test` is a list?

P.S. I am learning python using google's python exercise and I prefer using regular expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following to find if any of the strings in list starts with `'x'`

```
>>> [e for e in test if e.startswith('x')]
['xzz', 'xaa']
>>> any(e.startswith('x') for e in test)
True
```

Comment: I want to have the string started with "x" to be extracted, but I can't see your answer can give the output I expect.

Comment: can I use re.match or similar function in re library instead?

Comment: @lokheart You could definitely use `re.match` in place of `starswith` in the list comprehension above.

Comment: @squiguy tried `[x for x in test if re.match("^x",x)]` and it works

Comment: @lokheart Cool :). Have fun with Python!

Answer (score 22):

In general, you may use

```py
import re                                  # Add the re import declaration to use regex
test = ['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'] # Define a test list
reg = re.compile(r'^x')                    # Compile the regex
test = list(filter(reg.search, test))      # Create iterator using filter, cast to list 
# => ['xzz', 'xaa']
```

Or, to inverse the results and get all items that do not match the regex:

```py
list(filter(lambda x: not reg.search(x), test))
# >>> ['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AKHH88).

**USAGE NOTE**:

- [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) finds the first regex match *anywhere* in a string and returns a match object, otherwise `None`
- [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) looks for a match *only at the string start*, it does NOT require a full string match. So, `re.search(r'^x', text)` = `re.match(r'x', text)`
- [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) only returns a match if the full string matches the pattern, so, `re.fullmatch(r'x')` = `re.match(r'x\Z')` = `re.search(r'^x\Z')`.

If you wonder what the `r''` prefix means, see [Python - Should I be using string prefix r when looking for a period (full stop or .) using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249949/python-should-i-be-using-string-prefix-r-when-looking-for-a-period-full-stop) and  [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter).  I am assuming you want a new list with certain elements from the old one.

```
new_test = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('x'), test)
```

Or if you want to use a regular expression in the filter function you could try the following.
It requires the `re` module to be imported.

```
new_test = filter(lambda s: re.match("^x", s), test)
```

Answer (score 1):

An example when you want to extract more than one datapoint from each string in the list:

Input:

```
2021-02-08 20:43:16 [debug] : [RequestsDispatcher@_execute_request] Requesting: https://test.com&uuid=1623\n
```

Code:

```
pat = '(.* \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) .*_execute_request\] (.*?):.*uuid=(.*?)[\.\n]'
new_list = [re.findall(pat,s) for s in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[[('2021-02-08 20:43:15', 'Requesting', '1623')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some improvisation that works fine. Probably helps..

```
import re
l= ['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'] #list
s= str( " ".join(l))                   #flattening list to string
re.findall('\\bx\\S*', s)               #regex to find string starting with x

['xzz', 'xaa']
```