# How to filter out strings from a list of strings with dates?

Tags: python

How to filter out this list, so that we are left with only a list of strings that are in yyyy-mm-dd format?

```
2021-11-11
2021-10-01
some_folder
some_other_folder
```

so that we end up with a list like so:

```
2021-11-11
2021-10-01
```

Also what if the list has a prefix?

```
root/2021-11-11
root/2021-10-01
user/some_folder
root/some_other_folder
```

and we wanted to end up with:

```
root/2021-11-11
root/2021-10-01
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression to filter list of strings matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403021/python-regular-expression-to-filter-list-of-strings-matching-a-pattern)

Comment: hm how would i use regex to solve the question i posted with the edited version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would let `datetime` module handle that for me using `strptime`. If it is not in `'%Y-%m-%d'` format, it raises ValueError :

```
import datetime

lst = ['2021-11-11', '2021-10-01', 'some_folder', 'some_other_folder',
       'root/2021-11-11', 'root/2021-10-01',
       'user/some_folder', 'root/some_other_folder']


def filter_(s):
    last_part = s.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1]
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(last_part, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print([i for i in lst if filter_(i)])
```

output :

```
['2021-11-11', '2021-10-01', 'root/2021-11-11', 'root/2021-10-01']
```

Comment: Do you know how i can change your code to work for the edited version i posted? thanks :)

Comment: @caasswa If the dates appear at the end, you can `rsplit` the lines using slash and `maxsplit=1` then take the second.

Comment: could you write a quick example? sorry super noob at this...

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: btw, would i need to do `[-2]` if the strings all have a `/` at the end?

Comment: @caasswa In that case you can just add `.strip('/')` to strip the slash like : `last_part = s.strip('/').rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1]`. This will handle that.

Comment: thank you :) that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `re` library for this. Something like this.

Edit:
Changed my answer because of @SorousHBakhtiary's comment about an exception I forgot that happens when you modify an iterable object while iterating it.

```
import re

li = [
'root/2021-11-11',
'root/2021-10-01',
'user/some_folder',
'root/some_other_folder',
]

new_list = li.copy()

for string in new_list:
   if not re.fullmatch('.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$',string):
      li.remove(string)
```

This can also be done in one line using list comprehension:

```
li = [
'root/2021-11-11',
'root/2021-10-01',
'user/some_folder',
'root/some_other_folder',
]

li = [string for string in li if re.fullmatch('.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$',string)]
```

Comment: Useful for when the date is `২০২২-০৫-১৯`.

Comment: This is not working. You shouldn't remove something from a list while you are iterating over it. Simple fix is to use `for string in list.copy()`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary right, i forgot about that issue

Comment: what if it is like the question i edited? where it only matters if it ends with yyyy-mm-dd and not what is at the start?

Comment: @caasswa then you can just change the `re.fullmatch()` call to look like `re.fullmatch('.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$',string)``. The `.*` at the start and the `$` at the end of the regular expression will make the program look for any string that ends with something in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: interesting - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> filter_pattern = re.compile(r'.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$')
>>> 
>>> lst = [
... '2021-11-11', '2021-10-01', 'some_folder', 
... 'some_other_folder', 'root/2021-11-11', 'root/2021-10-01',
... 'user/some_folder', 'root/some_other_folder'
... ]
>>> 
>>> lst = [i for i in lst if (len(filter_pattern.findall(i) > 0)]
>>> 
>>> lst
```