# Splitting behavior for string prefixed with r

Tags: python, string, split

Can you please help me understand this behaviour:

```
>>> a = "abc\\def\\ghi"
>>> a.split(r"\\")
['abc\\def\\ghi']
```

However, after spending a few minutes and permutations, I found this to be working for now:

```
>>> a.split("\\")
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Can you point me to the literature/design-considerations that results in this behaviour?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Regex.  The `r` means [raw-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l), not Regex pattern.

Comment: Found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix

Comment: To expand on that a little: `r"\\"` is two backslashes; backslashes aren't treated as an escape character in a raw string. `"\\"` is one backslash.

Comment: Adding to what @iCodez said, you might often find raw strings used for regexes because the backslash is often used in a regex, and it's a pain to double them up all the time.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Stackoverflow is awesome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your string contains regular, single backslashes which have been escaped:

```
>>> a = "abc\\def\\ghi"
>>> a
'abc\\def\\ghi'
>>> print(a)
abc\def\ghi
```

When you split by `"\\"` you are escaping one backslash, so you are splitting by one backslash and will get a list of three elements: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi']`.
When you split by `r"\\"` you are splitting by **two** backslashes, because prefixing a string with `r` is Python's *raw string notation* (which has nothing to do with regexes). The important thing here is that backslashes are not handled in any special way in a raw string literal.

The reason you often see strings prefixed with `r` when you are looking at people's regex is that they do not want to escape backslash characters which also have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Some further reading with regards to regular expressions: [The Backslash Plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague)