# How to search wildcard . as a string in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

Here is my string (does not work in BigQuery):

> name = '0.2.4'

```
REGEXP_MATCH(name, '^0\\.2')
```

More Examples:

> name1 = 'com.example.dashboard'

If we write `REGEXP_MATCH(name, '^com.example')`
here `.` is wildcard entry which is means any character
so if `name1` is `comaexample` it also give true.

So to skip behavior of `.` we have to use `\`
but `REGEXP_MATCH(name, '^com\\.example')` gives error.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, are you sure of your `name` String ?

The following query always returns `true` :

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCH('0.2.4', '^0.2') FROM [mydataset.mytable] LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have edited my question Sorry! wildcard . here signifies any character not just .

Comment: It's not clear enough to me yet, can you give at list 2 or 3 example of strings that should match and strings that should not match ?

Comment: i have given one more example

Answer (score 1):

Try indicating that the pattern is a regular expression using `r`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCH('0.2.4', r'^0\.2')
```

This returns `true`. The alternative is to use two slashes, as in: `'^0\\.2'`

Comment: Thanks this works! why we have to say r at the starting if we dont provide r then what it means

Comment: 'r' means 'raw'. There is a good discussion of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix (in the context of python, but the same thing holds for bigquery SQL).