# How to use * or + with brackets in regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex

There are multiple space separated characters in the input eg: `string = "a b c d a s e "`

What should the pattern be such that when I do `re.search` on the input using the pattern, I'd get the `j`'th character along with the space following it in the input by using `.group(j)`?

I tried something of the sort `"^(([a-zA-Z])\s)+"` but this is not working. What should I do?

**EDIT**
My actual question is in the heading and the body described only a special case of it:
 Here's the general version of the question: if I have to take in all patterns of a specific type (initial question had the pattern "[a-zA-Z]\s") from a string, what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `findall()` instead and get the `j`-th match by index:

```
>>> j = 2
>>> re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]\s", string)[j]
'c '
```

where `[a-zA-Z]\s` would match a lower or upper case letter followed by a single space character.

Comment: uhm, what does 'r' mean in .findall(r"[a-zA-Z]\s",..) ?

Comment: @LucyferZedd this just means the string is "raw" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix).

Answer (score 5):

Why use `regex` when you can simply use `str.split()` method and access to the characters with a simple indexing?

```
>>> new = s.split()
>>> new
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 's', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
>>> string = "a b c d a s e "
>>> j=2
>>> re.search(r'([a-zA-Z]\s){%i}' % j, string).group(1)
'b '
```

Explanation:

1. With the pattern `([a-zA-Z]\s)` you capture a letter then the space;
2. With the repetition `{2}` added, you capture the last of the repetition -- in this case the second one (base 1 vs base 0 indexing...).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO6mO6/1)