# Python 3: Regex doesn't work when read text from file

Tags: python, regex, file, find

The following is my information:

The input:

```
 \"button\" \"button\" href=\"#\"   data-id=\"11111111111\"  \"button\" \"button\" href=\"#\"   data-id=\"222222222222\"
     \"button\" \"button\" href=\"#\"
```

The output I'd like:

```
11111111111
222222222222
```

My 1st code which worked well:

```
text = 'data-id=\"11111111111 \" data-id=\"222222222222\" '
c = re.findall('data-id=\\"(.*?)\\"', text)
```

My 2nd code which doesn't work. It show nothing

```
with open("E:/test.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readline()

c = re.findall('data-id=\\"(.*?)\\"', text)
```

Why my secondary code doesn't work. Please help me fix it. I highly appreciate you. Thank you :)

Comment: Your indentation is wrong if you want it to work.

Comment: Where is this kind of input coming from? It really looks like HTML-ish.

Comment: Please check my answer to know why your first code is working but not second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this answer. (Added two lines in str_txt.txt file).

Only change I did in your second code is , I have **'r' as prefix in regex**.
For more info on **'r' prefix in regex**, please [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix) !!!

```
import re
with open("str_txt.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
    c=[]
    c = re.findall(r'data-id=\\"(.*?)\\"', line)
    print c
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.Py
['11111111111', '222222222222']
['1111113434111', '222222222222']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
re.findall(r'"([^\\]+)\\"', s)
```

- `"([^\\]+)` matches a `"`, then the captured grouo contains the desired portion i.e. substring upto next `\`, `\\"` makes sure that the portion is followed by `\\"`

**Example:**

```
In [34]: s
Out[34]: 'randomtext data-id=\\"11111111111\\" randomtext data-id=\\"222222222222\\"'

In [35]: re.findall(r'"([^\\]+)\\"', s)
Out[35]: ['11111111111', '222222222222']
```

---

**Answer to edited question:**

Use `\d+` to match digits:

```
re.findall(r'"(\d+)\\"', s)
```

to match based on ID instead:

```
re.findall(r'data-id=\\"([^\\]+)\\"', s)
```

**Example:**

```
In [45]: s
Out[45]: '\\"button\\" \\"button\\" href=\\"#\\"   data-id=\\"11111111111\\"  \\"button\\" \\"button\\" href=\\"#\\"   data-id=\\"222222222222\\" \\"button\\" \\"button\\" href=\\"#\\"'

In [50]: re.findall(r'"(\d+)\\"', s)
Out[50]: ['11111111111', '222222222222']

In [46]: re.findall(r'data-id=\\"([^\\]+)\\"', s)
Out[46]: ['11111111111', '222222222222']
```

Comment: Hello, Your code worked great but my input is more complicated. I just updated the question. Sorry for that