# Python and Regex can't find sequence in string

Tags: python, regex, findall

Hi I have the following string:

```
t = '<td align="right" class="ofGridLinesTop" headers="amount" sortvalue="2633.33" valign="top">\n\t\t\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t$2,633.33\n\t\t\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t\t\t</td>'
```

I know that the following Regex sequence properly identifies the part of the string I want (sortvalue="2633.33")

```
\bsortvalue=.\b\d+.\d+.
```

Yet when I use the following statement:

```
Amt = re.findall('\bsortvalue=.\b\d+.\d+.',t)
```

I come up empty. Any idea why?

Comment: Try `r'\bsortvalue="(\d+\.\d+)"'` instead.

Comment: what about with this regex `'(sortvalue)(=)(".*?")'`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Amt = re.findall('\\bsortvalue=.\\b\d+.\d+.',t)
```

or this:

```
Amt = re.findall(r'\bsortvalue=.\b\d+.\d+.',t)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)

Comment: Correct answer but should explain; you're not escaping the backslash in `\b` etc so you're actually substituting those escape codes instead of what you intended (i.e. \b is backspace). To fix you can either escape the backslash i.e. `\\b` or create a raw string by prefixing the regex with `r` as in Horcrux' 2nd example which is essentially a string literal and as such ignores the escape characters.