# Using regular expression in pandas to select before a certain divider \r\

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hi I'm trying to without succeed to use regular expression to select he string before the \r\ , ideally in majority of the times is a word follow by a coma. But as showed the \r\ and some other obstacles appear .Example below:

```
    var
Sao Paulo , Brazil \r\n Details Description ....
Rio de Janeiro , Brazil  ... Pending funding.  

  (result)expected
Sao Paulo , Brasil
```

Comment: This is the code I have so far :    df['result'] = df['var'].str.extract('/^(.*?)\\r /', expand=True)
I get all NaN as a result

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
# using string function .find()
    a = 'Sao Paulo , Brazil \r\n Details Description ....'
    a[0:a.find('\r')].strip()

   'Sao Paulo , Brazil'
```

**Edit:**< br />

Let's say your data frame is df. The name of your column is 'text'. We'll create a new column say 'new_text'. Now, do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # just in case it's not a data.table
df[,new_text := text[0:text.find('\r')].strip()]
```

Comment: Hi and tks for such a quick reply. How I would apply to a data set containing 1 million rows? @Manish Saraswat

Comment: Just added that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
df["var"].str.extract("(.*)\\\\r")
```

or

```
df["var"].str.extract(r"(.*)\\r")
```

Notice the `r` before quotation mark. You can read more at [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)