# Do I need to include `r` before a regex search?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to split terms on a delimiter. I'd like to put the number as `index` and the name as `name`.

My terms:

```
The Beehive
12. Bar 821
13. Natives Bar
14. Last Call Bar
15. Scarlet Lounge
16. Linden Room
17. Rooftop 25
```

I'm using this code:

```
terms = ['The Beehive', '12. Bar 821', '13. Natives Bar', '14. Last Call Bar', '15. Scarlet Lounge', '16. Linden Room', '17. Rooftop 25']

delim = re.match('\d+\. ', terms)

if delim is None:
    print(delim)
else:
     index = index[:delim.end()]
     name = index[delim.end():]
```

This fails to capture the split. I've tested it by printing the delim and it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get any error at `delim = re.match('\d+\. ', terms)`. `terms` is a list and not a string

Answer (score 2):

You are using list as compared to string

```
import re
terms = ['The Beehive', '12. Bar 821', '13. Natives Bar', '14. Last Call Bar', '15. Scarlet Lounge', '16. Linden Room', '17. Rooftop 25']

delim = re.compile('\d+\.')
for term in terms:
    match = delim.search(term)
    if match:
        print(term[:match.end()]) #index
        print(term[match.end():]) #name
```

Comment: There's something weird with my text string. It wasn't matching because the space was actually an invisible character `~`. This worked `delim = re.match(r'\d+\.~', terms[i])`

Comment: Except it wasn't a tilde. It appears grey in my text editor and I can't copy and paste it to stack exchange. it appears as nothing when I copy/paste outside the editor

Answer (score 0):

The [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) function accepts only individual strings, so you have to iterate over `terms` separately:

```
>>> for term in terms:
...     match = re.match(r'^(?P<index>(\d+\. )?)(?P<name>.*)$', term)  # Return a match object which contains the named groups.
...     index, _, name = match.groups()  # Unpack the groups.
...     # index = match.group('index')
...     # name = match.group('name')
...     print(index, name)
... 
 The Beehive
12.  Bar 821
13.  Natives Bar
14.  Last Call Bar
15.  Scarlet Lounge
16.  Linden Room
17.  Rooftop 25
```

Also notice the use of [groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) in the regular expression, which returns a [Group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) object with named matches.

Regarding whether to use the `r''` prefix or not, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix) or this excerpt from the docs:

> The r prefix, making the literal a raw string literal, is needed […] because escape sequences in a normal “cooked” string literal that are not recognized by Python, as opposed to regular expressions, now result in a `DeprecationWarning` and will eventually become a `SyntaxError`. See [The Backslash Plague](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).