# Why am I getting a `SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \s` warning?

Tags: python-3.x

```
re.compile('\s+', flags = re.UNICODE)
```

The above code gives the following warning in python3.

```
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \s
```

I fix it by using `r'\s+'`. Is it a correct way to fix the problem?

Comment: either use `r'\s+'` or `'\\s+'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that is. You can either use a raw string `r'\s+'` or alternatively escape the backslash with `'\\s+'`.