# How to strip all whitespace from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, spaces, strip

How do I strip all the spaces in a python string? For example, I want a string like `strip my spaces` to be turned into `stripmyspaces`, but I cannot seem to accomplish that with `strip()`:

```
>>> 'strip my spaces'.strip()
'strip my spaces'
```

Comment: Note that str.strip only affects leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: ..and it doesn’t take care of Unicode de facto whitespace, like the zero-width space. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3739928/2693875 for the details.

Comment: 'strip my spaces'.replace(' ', '')

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Taking advantage of str.split's behavior with no sep parameter:

```
>>> s = " \t foo \n bar "
>>> "".join(s.split())
'foobar'
```

If you just want to remove spaces instead of all whitespace:

```
>>> s.replace(" ", "")
'\tfoo\nbar'
```

### Premature optimization

Even though efficiency isn't the primary goal—writing clear code is—here are some initial timings:

```
$ python -m timeit '"".join(" \t foo \n bar ".split())'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import re' 're.sub(r"\s+", "", " \t foo \n bar ")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 usec per loop
```

Note the regex is cached, so it's not as slow as you'd imagine.  Compiling it beforehand helps some, but would only matter in practice if you call this *many* times:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import re; e = re.compile(r"\s+")' 'e.sub("", " \t foo \n bar ")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.76 usec per loop
```

Even though re.sub is 11.3x slower, remember your bottlenecks are assuredly elsewhere.  Most programs would not notice the difference between any of these 3 choices.

Comment: It's probably slower than `\s+` substitution. I'd stick with re.

Comment: @OTZ: You might be surprised, but see the "remember" note.

Comment: @Roger Hmm. interesting. Have you tried the `s.translate` method by any chance? It probably beats all the methods shown on this page.

Comment: @Roger Pate: You don't need the 'table' argument for translate, it can be `None` -- although, surprisingly, that makes it slower...

Comment: One other thing. Passing " " as the second argument to translate doesn't strip out all forms of whitespace.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks; help(str.translate) lied to me! (It says table must be a string of length 256.)  I'll just remove that section; fixing the various issues isn't worth it.  (Anyone curious: check revision history.)

Comment: Try `myString.translate(None, " \t\r\n\v")`. It only takes 83% as long as Roger's fastest (split and join) technique. Not sure if it covers all the white space characters that split does, but it will probably suffice for most ASCII applications.

Comment: This does not work with all strings. Try running this on ```"""http://myserver.com/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];
            (
              way["building"="house"](40,-74,40,-74);
            );
            out body;
            >;
            out skel qt;"""``` EDIT comment does not seem to support whitespace =(

Comment: I did not know that .split() will catch any kind of whitespace and I bet the next person reading my code won't know that either (this includes my future self six months from now).

Answer (score 87):

For Python 3:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', 'strip my \n\t\r ASCII and \u00A0 \u2003 Unicode spaces')
'stripmyASCIIandUnicodespaces'
>>> # Or, depending on the situation:
>>> re.sub(r'(\s|\u180B|\u200B|\u200C|\u200D|\u2060|\uFEFF)+', '', \
... '\uFEFF\t\t\t strip all \u000A kinds of \u200B whitespace \n')
'stripallkindsofwhitespace'
```

...handles any whitespace characters that you're not thinking of - and believe us, there are plenty.

`\s` on its own always covers the ASCII whitespace:

- (regular) space
- tab
- new line (\n)
- carriage return (\r)
- form feed
- vertical tab

Additionally:

- for Python 2 with `re.UNICODE` enabled,
- for Python 3 without any extra actions,

...`\s` also covers the Unicode whitespace characters, for example:

- non-breaking space,
- em space,
- ideographic space,

...etc. See the full list [here, under "Unicode characters with White_Space property"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#Whitespace).

However `\s` DOES NOT cover characters not classified as whitespace, which are de facto whitespace, such as among others:

- zero-width joiner,
- Mongolian vowel separator,
- zero-width non-breaking space (a.k.a. [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)),

...etc. See the full list [here, under "Related Unicode characters without White_Space property"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#Whitespace).

So these 6 characters are covered by the list in the second regex, `\u180B|\u200B|\u200C|\u200D|\u2060|\uFEFF`.

Sources:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property

Comment: This is a lot less hacky of a solution then the accepted answer.

Comment: This is more explicit than the other answers, so it takes the cake for me.

Comment: The accepted answer is old, from the times where almost noone used Python 3 and therefore does not cover Unicode strings. It also unnecessarily go into optimization, which was not asked for. That's why I updated this answer as the best, in my opinion.

Comment: @GregDubicki thanks for the additions. I added back the simple option since the full list might be overkill in some situations, or harmful if you need to keep a BOM (but hopefully you don't). Also noted the MVS since it is my favorite Unicode character, and was still Zs back when I originally wrote this. :P

Comment: Thanks @TimYates! I made one more change to completely split the ASCII-only case from the UTF-8 one. This answer got long now, but more readable and easier to quickly copy-paste, as everyone likes that. ;)

Comment: That edit seemed misleading (`\s` is enough in many situations with Unicode strings, not just ASCII) and added complexity by stressing Python 2 (which is EOL now, and the question is tagged Python 3). I think the brief mention of Python 2 and the explanation about the differences is enough info to choose the right approach.

Comment: Ok, I am good with that @TimYates . :) I just made an almost empty edit because I think I deserve to be visible as an Editor of this answer.

Answer (score 42):

Alternatively,

```
"strip my spaces".translate( None, string.whitespace )
```

And here is Python3 version:

```
"strip my spaces".translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.whitespace))
```

Comment: this seems the most pythonic. why hasn't it been upvoted to the top?

Comment: Python 3 code in answer does work. Comment from @DanMenes is obsolete

Comment: `NameError: name 'string' is not defined`.

Comment: @ZelphirKaltstahl you need to `import string`

Comment: `string.whitespace` is only ASCII whitespace, so this will fail on strings containing stuff like U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 20):

### Remove the Starting Spaces in Python

```
string1 = "    This is Test String to strip leading space"
print(string1)
print(string1.lstrip())
```

### Remove the Trailing or End Spaces in Python

```
string2 = "This is Test String to strip trailing space     "
print(string2)
print(string2.rstrip())
```

### Remove the whiteSpaces from Beginning and end of the string in Python

```
string3 = "    This is Test String to strip leading and trailing space      "
print(string3)
print(string3.strip())
```

### Remove all the spaces in python

```
string4 = "   This is Test String to test all the spaces        "
print(string4)
print(string4.replace(" ", ""))
```

Answer (score 17):

The simplest is to use replace:

```
"foo bar\t".replace(" ", "").replace("\t", "")
```

Alternatively, use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub(r"\s", "", "foo bar\t")
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Roger Pate following code worked for me:

```
s = " \t foo \n bar "
"".join(s.split())
'foobar'
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run following code:

```
i=0
ProductList=[]
while i < len(new_list): 
   temp=''                            # new_list[i]=temp=' Plain   Utthapam  '
   #temp=new_list[i].strip()          #if we want o/p as: 'Plain Utthapam'
   temp="".join(new_list[i].split())  #o/p: 'PlainUtthapam' 
   temp=temp.upper()                  #o/p:'PLAINUTTHAPAM' 
   ProductList.append(temp)
   i=i+2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a regex with `re.sub`. You can search for all whitespace and replace with an empty string.

`\s` in your pattern will match whitespace characters - and not just a space (tabs, newlines, etc). You can read more about it [in the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: I dunno how to use regexes :(

Comment: @wrongusername: Updated with a link to the re module manual page.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
re.sub(' ','','strip my spaces')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "how to remove all white space". It only remove spaces

Answer (score 3):

The standard techniques to filter a list apply, although they are not as efficient as the `split/join` or `translate` methods.

We need a set of whitespaces:

```
>>> import string
>>> ws = set(string.whitespace)
```

The `filter` builtin:

```
>>> "".join(filter(lambda c: c not in ws, "strip my spaces"))
'stripmyspaces'
```

A list comprehension (yes, use the brackets: see benchmark below):

```
>>> import string
>>> "".join([c for c in "strip my spaces" if c not in ws])
'stripmyspaces'
```

A fold:

```
>>> import functools
>>> "".join(functools.reduce(lambda acc, c: acc if c in ws else acc+c, "strip my spaces"))
'stripmyspaces'
```

Benchmark:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('"".join("strip my spaces".split())')
0.17734256500003198
>>> timeit('"strip my spaces".translate(ws_dict)', 'import string; ws_dict = {ord(ws):None for ws in string.whitespace}')
0.457635745999994
>>> timeit('re.sub(r"\s+", "", "strip my spaces")', 'import re')
1.017787621000025

>>> SETUP = 'import string, operator, functools, itertools; ws = set(string.whitespace)'
>>> timeit('"".join([c for c in "strip my spaces" if c not in ws])', SETUP)
0.6484303600000203
>>> timeit('"".join(c for c in "strip my spaces" if c not in ws)', SETUP)
0.950212219999969
>>> timeit('"".join(filter(lambda c: c not in ws, "strip my spaces"))', SETUP)
1.3164566040000523
>>> timeit('"".join(functools.reduce(lambda acc, c: acc if c in ws else acc+c, "strip my spaces"))', SETUP)
1.6947649049999995
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **Parce** your string to separate words
2. **Strip** white spaces on both sides
3. **Join** them with single space in the end

Final line of code:

```
' '.join(word.strip() for word in message_text.split()
```

Comment: missing a bracket

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR**

This solution was tested using Python 3.6

To strip all spaces from a string in Python3 you can use the following function:

```py
def remove_spaces(in_string: str):
    return in_string.translate(str.maketrans({' ': ''})
```

To remove any whitespace characters (' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c') you can use the following function:

```py
import string
def remove_whitespace(in_string: str):
    return in_string.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.whitespace)))
```

**Explanation**

Python's `str.translate` method is a built-in class method of str, it takes a table and returns a copy of the string with each character mapped through the passed translation table. [Full documentation for str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

To create the translation table `str.maketrans` is used. This method is another built-in class method of `str`. Here we use it with only one parameter, in this case a dictionary, where the keys are the characters to be replaced mapped to values with the characters replacement value. It returns a translation table for use with `str.translate`. [Full documentation for str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

The `string` module in python contains some common string operations and constants. `string.whitespace` is a constant which returns a string containing all ASCII characters that are considered whitespace. This includes the characters space, tab, linefeed, return, formfeed, and vertical tab. [Full documentation for string.whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.whitespace)

In the second function `dict.fromkeys` is used to create a dictionary where the keys are the characters in the string returned by `string.whitespace` each with value `None`. [Full documentation for dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

Answer (score 1):

If optimal performance is not a requirement and you just want something dead simple, you can define a basic function to test each character using the string class's built in "isspace" method:

```
def remove_space(input_string):
    no_white_space = ''
    for c in input_string:
        if not c.isspace():
            no_white_space += c
    return no_white_space
```

Building the `no_white_space` string this way will not have ideal performance, but the solution is easy to understand.

```
>>> remove_space('strip my spaces')
'stripmyspaces'
```

If you don't want to define a function, you can convert this into something vaguely similar with list comprehension. Borrowing from the top answer's `join` solution:

```
>>> "".join([c for c in "strip my spaces" if not c.isspace()])
'stripmyspaces'
```

Comment: Curious: what about this is not 'optimal performance'? Specifically, your first example, the remove_space() function.

Comment: I'm not sure what the current state of Python's string handling is, but in the past string concatenation (foo_str+=bar_str) in Python used to have not so great performance. For light usage my example would be fine, but for processing large strings performance could become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using plain old **list comprehension**:

```
''.join([c for c in aString if c not in [' ','\t','\n']])
```

Example:

```
>>> aStr = 'aaa\nbbb\t\t\tccc  '
>>> print(aString)
aaa
bbb         ccc

>>> ''.join([c for c in aString if c not in [' ','\t','\n']])
'aaabbbccc'
```

Answer (score 0):

This got asked in an interview. So if you have to give a solution just by using strip method. Here's an approach -

```
s='string with spaces'
res=''.join((i.strip(' ') for i in s))
print(res)
```