# How to remove white spaces from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, whitespace

I need to remove spaces from a string in python. For example.

```
str1 = "TN 81 NZ 0025"

str1sp = nospace(srt1)

print(str1sp)

>>>TN81NZ0025
```

Comment: Please read [FAQ] first. Show what have you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip all whitespace from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```
>>> s = "TN 81 NZ 0025"
>>> s.replace(" ", "")
'TN81NZ0025'
```

To remove all types of white-space characters use `str.translate`:

```
>>> from string import whitespace
>>> s = "TN 81   NZ\t\t0025\nfoo"
# Python 2
>>> s.translate(None, whitespace)
'TN81NZ0025foo'
# Python 3
>>> s.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, whitespace)))
'TN81NZ0025foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can replace every spaces by the [`string.replace()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> "TN 81 NZ 0025".replace(" ", "")
'TN81NZ0025'
```

Or every whitespaces caracthers (included `\t` and `\n`) with a regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', "TN 81 NZ 0025")
'TN81NZ0025'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', "TN 81 NZ\t0025")  # Note the \t character here
'TN81NZ0025'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = "TN 81 NZ 0025"
s = ''.join(s.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Mind that in python strings are immutable and string replace function returns a string with the replaced value. If you are not executing the statement at the shell but inside a file,

```
 new_str = old_str.replace(" ","" )
```

This will replace all the white spaces in the string. If you want to replace only the first n white spaces,

```
new_str = old_str.replace(" ","", n)
```

where n is a number.

Answer (score 1):

One line of code to remove all extra spaces before, after, and within a sentence:

```
string = "  TN 81 NZ 0025  "
string = ''.join(filter(None,string.split(' ')))
```

Explanation:

1. Split entire string into list.
2. Filter empty elements from list.
3. Rejoin remaining elements with nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multiple spaces into a desired pattern by using following ways. Here your pattern is blank string.

```
import re
pattern = ""
re.sub(r"\s+", pattern, your_string)
```

or

```
import re
pattern = ""
re.sub(r" +", "", your_string)
```