# Palindrome recursion with whitespace and a function not working

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a palindrome recursion function, which works for every word except for ones with spaces. How do I fix the code to not take spaces into account?

```
def ispalindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2: 
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]: 
        return False
    return ispalindrome(word[1:-1])
print(ispalindrome("taco cat"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove white spaces from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991605/how-to-remove-white-spaces-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Just use word = word.strip() in the first line of the function

Comment: Remove spaces with `word = word.replace(" ", "")` at the top of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Solution:
    def recursive(self,s:str):
        string=''.join(char.lower() for char in s if char.isalnum())
        def dfs(s:str):
            if len(s)<=1:
                return True
            if s[0]==s[-1]:
                #reduce the bigger problem to smaller problem
                return dfs(s[1:-1])
        return dfs(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply modify the string so that the whitespace can be gone. one method is using the split join functions of python and the other is the usage of regex.

here's a sample of a running code:

```
def ispalindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2: 
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]: 
        return False
    return ispalindrome(word[1:-1])

print(ispalindrome(''.join("taco cat".split())))
```

Output: True

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Add that line in the function. This will remove white spaces and other tabular information.

```py
def ispalindrome(word):
    word = word.strip() # remote white spaces and tabular information
    if len(word) < 2: 
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]: 
        return False
    return ispalindrome(word[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove spaces in string at the beginning of the function, because space is a character too and function check for it too.

```
def ispalindrome(word):
    word = word.replace(' ', '')
    if len(word) < 2: 
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]: 
        return False
    return ispalindrome(word[1:-1])
print(ispalindrome("taco cat"))
```

There are different ways to remove spaces from string, these are:

1)

`string = string.replace(" ", "")`

2)

`string = "".join(string.split())`

3)

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+') 
string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

4)

```
import string 
string = string.translate(None, ' \n\t\r')
```