# Removing spaces from lines in python

Tags: python

I've been making this script to extract prices from a shopping site to get opportunities for best prices,however idk why i can not remove spaces from lines  tried strip and re but none seems to be working .
thanks for your answers
I'm a medical staff interested n programming that's why I'm not very skilled 
Heres is the code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
file = open('weird.txt' , "w+" , encoding='utf8')
out = open("output.txt" , "w+" , encoding = 'UTF-8')
url = "https://www.lioncomputer.com/computer/computer-components/motherboard.html?lion_599=26179%2C26175&product_list_dir=asc"
page = requests.get(url)
page = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page , 'html5lib')
file.write(soup.prettify())
soup2 = soup.find('ol' , class_ = 'products list items product-items')
item = soup2.find_all('div' ,class_ ="product details product-item-details")
for i in item :
    name =i.find(class_= "product-item-link")
    name = name.get_text()
    price = i.find(class_="price-box price-final_price")
    price = price.get_text()
# text = i.find('a' , class_ = 'product-item-link')
    out.write(("{0}:{1}".format(name,price)))
with open('outpuT.txt' , "w+") as f :
    for line in f:
        cleaned = line.replace((re.find((' ')[6])), '')
        cleaned = cleaned.strip()
        f.write(cleaned)
```

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: A similar question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string Hope it helps!

Comment: have you tried strip method?

Comment: Yes as i mentioned in title  i tried strip and re but no use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove white spaces from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991605/how-to-remove-white-spaces-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replace function in python to remove blank spaces.

```
newUpdatedString = oldString.replace("  ","")
```

However, also keep in mind that this command will remove all consecutive spaces.

Comment: Tried but not working can you please run the code i get spaces which is a part of title in site i checked there is a Title =  "stuff im looking for "but dont know how to get it

Comment: The site you're trying to access is returning a 403 forbidden code. I can't do much with that :(

Comment: Ah sryy iranian security logic :dont let them connect from foreign ip incase got hacked we can easily find lol i can send page source if u want