# How to remove single space between text

Tags: python, r

This is the input given `"S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y"`
(single space between each letter but 2 space between SHANNON and BRADLEY)
I want output to be in this format (given below)

`SHANNON BRADLEY`

Any way to do this in R or Python

Comment: Have you tried searching for string replacement? http://rseek.org/?q=string+replace

Comment: Have you even searched before asking here? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string

Comment: Between each letter there is one space and between SHANNON and BRADLEY there are 2 spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this in `R`

```
text <- c("S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y")

gsub(" (?! )" , text , replacement = "" , perl = T)
```

this is another simpler one

```
gsub("\\b " , text , replacement = "" , perl = T)
```

Comment: easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

If all letters are separated by one space and all words by two, then you could do something like this:

```
In [2]: "S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y".replace('  ', '   ')[::2]
Out[2]: 'SHANNON BRADLEY'
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution (probably a fast one), and who would actually think to replace with adding a space!

Comment: Please add the language used.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in python using :

```
    import re
    s = "S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y"
    ' '.join([''.join(i.split()) for i in re.split(r' {2,}',s)])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Python :**

```
import sys

myText="S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y" 
for i in range(len(myText)):
    if (myText[i]!=" " or myText[i+1]==" "):
        sys.stdout.write(myText[i])
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Python implementation:

```
" ".join(["".join(w.split(" ")) for w in "S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y".split("  ")])
```

This one-liner would convert it to the required output format.

Explanation:
The outer-most split function splits the string into words, the list comprehension reformats them, and the outer-most join re-attaches the words together.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in `R` with `gsub`:

```
gsub(" ([^ ])", "\\1", "S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y")
# [1] "SHANNON BRADLEY"
```

Comment: Or `gsub('([^ ]) ', '\\1', text)` ;)

Comment: actually there would be an issue on `text =' DOG '` either way.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, but text is not supposed to look like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In R:

```
x <- "S H A N N O N     B R A D L E Y"
paste(gsub(' ', '', unlist(strsplit(x, split = '     '))), collapse = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation:

```
import re
re.sub(' (?! )', '', "S H A N N O N  B R A D L E Y")
#"SHANNON BRADLEY"
```

Comment: That looks like python.

Answer (score 0):

In Python

```
In [1]: s="S H A N N O N     B R A D L E Y"
In [2]: "".join( [i.replace(' ','')  if i !='' else i.replace('',' ') for i in s.split('  ') ])
Out[2]: 'SHANNON BRADLEY'
```