# Accepting comma separated numbers along with splitting blanks in python

Tags: python

I am trying to accept a sequence of integers separated by comma and would like to trim any blanks that come along with it. I am using below code.

```
values = raw_input("Input some comma seprated numbers : ")
print "Values are", values

Arr = values.split(",")
print "Arr is", Arr

a = [int(x) for x in Arr.split()]
print "a is", a
```

While executing the above snippet, I am getting following exception,

```
$ python accept.py
Input some comma seprated numbers : 1,3, 2
Values are 1,3, 2
Arr is ['1', '3', ' 2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accept.py", line 20, in <module>
    a = int(Arr)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I could succeed by altering the code if I give input such as 1,3,2 or 1 3 2. But the problem arise if I mix both.

Using Python version 2. ( would not mind Python3 solution :) )

Answer (score 2):

The example output doesn't match the snipplet you provided, since error line is `a = int(Arr)`. In the example code there is also a `split()` on `Arr`, which should raise an `AttributeError`, since `Arr` is already a list.

To remove whitespace from the beginning/end of the string, use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method:

```
l = values.split(",")
a = [int(x.strip()) for x in l]
```

`ValueError` is raised if the array contains strings that can not be converted to integers, including when there is whitespace between digits.

If you want to remove *all* whitespace, including between digits (turning "1 2 3" to "123"), you can use something like <sup><sup>[[src]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string)</sup></sup>:

```
l = "".join(values.split())
a = [int(x.strip()) for x in l.split(",")]
```

Answer (score -1):

Python 3.6

```
values = input("Input some comma seprated numbers : ")
print("Values are :", values) #Output: 1,2 3,4

val = ",".join(values.split(" "))
print("Values seperated with comma :", val) #Output: 1,2,3,4

a = val.split(',')
print("a is", a) #Output: a is ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Well you just did the inverse of what was asked 