# .strip() doesn't work for ultra-long string

Tags: python-3.x

I am deeply depressed with the "\n" removal issue.

While it works perfectly for short strings, like:

```
str1 = "\n Star\nbucks has\n the \nbest coffee \n"
print(type(str1))
newstr = str1.strip()
print(newstr)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
Star
bucks has
 the
best coffee
```

...it doesn't work at all when I try to do the same with ultra-long string (which has the same type - <class 'str'>!) previously been read from file (Netscaler config been got with get.requests, about 450Kb) , nothing happens, the text is left intact, all the "\n" are still here.

Again, the short string and the long string, read from file, have the same type - <class 'str'>

What could be the problem here?

Please, see the small part of the long string:

```
192.168.113.115\nadd server H_ARCAAZ13XV 192.168.113.117\nadd server H_ARCAAZ11LG 192.168.213.154\nadd server H_ARCAAZ12LG 192.168.213.156\nadd server H_ARCAAZ13LG 192.168.213.158\nadd server H_ARCAAZ11RF 192.168.213.153\nadd server H_ARCAAZ12RF 192.168.213.155\nadd server H_ARCAAZ13RF 192.168.213.157\nadd server H_DE1-S912 172.25.235.20\nadd server H_DE1-S911 192.168.238.40\nadd server H_EXCMBX12XV 192.168.114.18\nadd server H_EXCMBX13XV 192.168.114.20\nadd server H_EXCMBX14XV 192.168.114.21\nadd server H_PBIAAZ01XV 192.168.137.182\nadd server H_PBIAAZ02XV 192.168.137.183\nadd server H_PBIAAZ03XV 192.168.137.184\nadd server H_PBIAAZ05DR 192.168.104.104\nadd server H_PBIAAZ06DR 192.168.104.108\nadd server H_PBIAAZ07DR 192.168.104.106\nadd server H_PBIAAZ08DR 192.168.104.110\nadd server H_SSMSM05XV 192.168.120.235\nadd server H_OPEAAZ01XV 192.168.112.51\nadd server H_OPEAAZ02XV 192.168.112.52\nadd server H_CUBAAZ11LG 192.168.213.148\nadd server H_CUBAAZ12LG 192.168.213.166\nadd server H_CUBAAZ11XV 192.168.113.125\nadd server H_CUBAAZ12XV 192.168.113.126\nadd server H_SPSWEB01AZ 192.168.210.34\nadd server H_SPSWEB02AZ 192.168.210.35\nadd server H_EMGAAZ01XV 192.168.113.127\nadd server H_EMGAAZ02XV 192.168.113.128\nadd server H_PBIAAZ09XV 192.168.137.191\nadd server H_IMOSAAZ01AZ 192.168.212.57\nadd server H_IMOSAAZ02AZ 192.168.212.58\nadd server 192.168.206.178 192.168.206.178\nadd server opeaAZ02qa 192.168.206.181\nadd server H_LYCEPS01XV 192.168.125.51\nadd server H_LYCEPS02XV 192.168.125.52\nadd server H_LYCEPS03XV 192.168.125.53\nadd server H_OFFAAZ01XV 192.168.120.152\nadd server H_OFFAAZ02XV 192.168.120.153\nadd server H_CTXSTF01XV 192.168.128.111\nadd server H_CTXSTF02XV 192.168.128.110\nadd server H_SPSLGL01XV 192.168.110.21\nadd server H_SPSLGL02XV 192.168.110.22\nadd server H_FAX01LONUK 192.168.115.11\nadd server H_FAX02LONUK 192.168.115.12\nadd server H_ADSVR01XV 192.168.120.163\nadd server H_ADSVR02XV 192.168.120.164\nadd server H_MSLG-XVSAAZ01 192.168.206.75\nadd server H_MSLG-XVSAAZ02 192.168.206.74\nadd server H_MSXV-XVSAAZ01 192.168.106.152\nadd server H_MSXV-XVSAAZ02 192.168.106.153\nadd server 172.20.0.20 172.20.0.20\nadd server 172.20.0.10 172.20.0.10\nadd server 172.20.0.101 172.20.0.101\nadd server H_EPMWEB01XV 192.168.119.47\nadd server H_EPMWEB02XV 192.168.119.48\nadd server 192.168.206.171 192.168.206.171\nadd server 192.168.206.58 192.168.206.58\nadd server 192.168.213.160 192.168.213.160\nadd server 192.168.213.159 192.168.213.159\nadd server 192.168.213.162 192.168.213.162\nadd server 192.168.213.65 192.168.213.65\nadd server 192.168.213.169 192.168.213.169\nadd server 192.168.112.113 192.168.112.113\nadd server H_WGXV-FSMAAZ02 172.16.49.15\nadd server H_WGCN-FSMAAZ02 172.16.49.16\nadd server H_WGXV-SPTAAZ01 172.16.21.170\nadd server H_WGXV-SPTAAZ02 172.16.21.169\nadd server H_WGCN-SPTAAZ01 172.16.1.155\nadd server H_WGCN-SPTAAZ02 172.16.1.157\nadd server H_MSLG-EWASVR01 192.168.206.77\nadd server H_MSLG-EWASVR02 192.168.206.78\nadd server H_MSXV-MGOOPS01 192.168.120.139\nadd server H_MSXV-MGOOPS03 192.168.120.140\nadd server H_EPMWEB01AZ 192.168.219.30\nadd server H_EPMWEB02AZ 192.168.219.31\nadd server H_CUBWEB01XV 192.168.113.28\nadd server H_CUBWEB02XV 192.168.113.29\nadd server H_EPMAAZ01XV 192.168.119.49\nadd server H_EPMAAZ02XV 192.168.119.50\nadd server H_EPMAAZ01AZ 192.168.219.32\nadd server H_EPMAAZ02AZ 192.168.219.33\nadd server H_STSAAZ01LG 192.168.206.51\nadd server H_STSAAZ02LG 192.168.206.52\nadd server H_RVCAAZ01LG 192.168.213.115\nadd server H_RVCAAZ02LG 192.168.213.116\nadd server H_RVCAAZ03LG 192.168.213.61\nadd server H_RVCAAZ04LG 192.168.213.62\nadd server H_MSLG-MODAAZ01 192.168.206.92 -comment NZ871779\nadd server H_MSLG-MODAAZ02 192.168.206.91 -comment NZ871779\nadd server H_MSXV-MODAAZ01 192.168.106.158\nadd server H_MSXV-MODAAZ02 192.168.106.159\nadd server H_MSIT-XVSAAZ01 192.168.206.162\nadd server H_MSIT-XVSAAZ02 192.168.206.163\nadd server H_MSXV-EWASVR01 192.168.106.154\nadd server H_MSXV-EWASVR02 192.168.106.155\nadd server H_MSIT-MODAAZ01 192.168.222.109\nadd server H_MSIT-MODAAZ02 192.168.222.110\nadd server H_MSLG-XVSWEB01 192.168.222.106\nadd server H_MSLG-XVSWEB02 192.168.222.105\nadd server H_MSLG-MODAAZ03 192.168.222.116\nadd server H_MSLG-MODAAZ04 192.168.222.117\nadd server H_BISIS01XV01 192.168.118.15\nadd server H_BISIS01XV02 192.168.118.16\nadd server H_MSXV-XVSWEB01 192.168.113.134\nadd server H_MSXV-XVSWEB02 192.168.113.135\nadd server H_MSFF-EWASVR01 192.168.222.135\nadd server H_MSFF-EWASVR02 192.168.222.136\nadd server H_MSIT-MODAAZ03 192.168.222.148\nadd server H_MSIT-MODAAZ04 192.168.222.57\nadd server H_MSFF-XVSWEB01 192.168.222.146\nadd server H_MSFF-XVSWEB02 192.168.222.147\nadd server H_MSIT-XVSWEB02 192.168.222.60\nadd server H_MSIT-XVSWEB01 192.168.222.59\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ05 192.168.110.55\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ06 192.168.110.57\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ07 192.168.110.58\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ08 192.168.110.60\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ11 192.168.110.65\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ12 192.168.110.63\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ13 192.168.110.62\nadd server H_MSXV-SPSAAZ14 192.168.110.64\nadd server H_MSRF-JEASVR01 172.16.1.177\nadd server H_GELG-RTPSFN01 192.168.229.76\nadd server H_GELG-RTPSFN02 192.168.229.77\nadd server H_GELG-RTPSFN03 192.168.229.78\nadd server H_GELG-RTPDSN01 192.168.229.79\nadd server H_GELG-RTPDSN02 192.168.229.81\nadd server H_GELG-RTPDSN03 192.168.229.80\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPSFN01 192.168.113.142\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPSFN02 192.168.113.141\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPSFN03 192.168.113.143\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPDSN01 192.168.113.156\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPDSN02 192.168.113.153\nadd server H_GEXV-RTPDSN03 192.168.113.155\nadd server H_CUBAAZ11LG2 192.168.206.180\nadd server H_MSLG-ABAAAZ01 192.168.221.61\nadd server H_MSLG-ABAAAZ02 192.168.227.217\nadd server H_WGRF-GSXAAZ03 172.16.1.179\nadd server H_WGQA-GSXAAZ01 172.16.1.180\nadd server H_WGCN-GSXAAZ02 172.16.1.181\nadd server H_WGCN-GSXAAZ03 172.16.1.182\nadd server H_WGXV-GSXAAZ02 172.16.21.166\nadd server H_WGXV-GSXAAZ03 172.16.21.182\nadd server 192.168.240.180 192.168.240.180\nadd server 10.3.74.180 10.3.74.180\nadd server H_SSXV-TSGSVR11 192.168.120.148\nadd server H_MSXV-ABAAAZ01 192.168.113.151\nadd server H_MSXV-ABAAAZ02 192.168.113.145\nadd server H_MSANOD11AZ 192.168.206.35\nadd server H_MSANOD12AZ 192.168.206.254\n
```

Comment: `string.strip()` without arguments [removes white spaces from left and right of string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). The long string mentioned doesn't contain a leading white space (or new-line) character.

Comment: Sorry, but why? The short string contains the "\n" in the middle, as well as the long string... like here: 192.168.113.115\nadd server H_ARCAAZ13XV

Comment: Yes, `string.strip()` does nothing to it, as you show in your output. Line changes occur as normal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip all whitespace from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is not supposed to do what you intend. It removes the characters given as its argument (whitespace by default) from the beginning and the end of the string, not from somewhere in the middle. You just thought it had removed the `\n` occurrences because of the way `print()` works: it executes `\n` as a line break. Note that the short string where you thought the `\n`s were removed is printed across several lines.

Instead, you want to use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), like this:

```py
newstr = str1.replace('\n', '')
```

This should also work with the longer string, as the length of the string was never the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the .replace('\n', '') doesn't help me, the \n are still here: with open('IntDC1.txt') as f:
    mylist = f.read()

conf = mylist.replace('\n', '')

print(conf)

Comment: If you read the text from a file and store it in a list of lines, you can concatenate those lines into one string with `''.join(mylist)`.

Comment: I regret to report, that it doesn't solve this as well...

with open('IntDC1.txt') as f:
    print (" ".join(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f))

Comment: Oh, I've just got this!!! The file itself is the ultra long string, it has been created via get.requests:

lbvs_response=requests.get("https://192.168.150.7/nitro/v1/config/nsrunningconfig",auth=(NITRO_USER,   NITRO_PWD),verify=False)
Configuration=lbvs_response.text
WriteImplementationScriptToFile=open('IntDC1.txt', "a")
WriteImplementationScriptToFile.write(str(Configuration))

The data I get from get.request already contains these "\n"

So, my task is opposite - I have to remove the \n and split the one ultra-long string into lines.

Comment: Okay, then you can use `str.split('\n')`, where `str` is the name of the long string. This will return a list of lines.