# trying to create a dictionary but do not know how to deal with \n

Tags: python

```
subject_dic = {}
inputFile = open(filename)
for line in inputFile:
    split_line = string.split(line, ',')
    subject_dic[split_line[0]] = tuple(split_line[1:3])
print subject_dic
```

I'm getting

```
{'6.08': ('1', '10\n'), '6.09': ('3', '7\n'), '6.19': ('8', '19'), '6.10': ('8', '18\n'), '6.00': ('10', '1\n'), '6.01': ('5', '4\n'), '6.02': ('5', '6\n'), '6.03': ('2', '9\n'), '6.04': ('1', '2\n'), '6.05': ('1', '18\n'), '6.06': ('5', '19\n'), '6.07': ('2', '10\n'), '6.13': ('9', '16\n'), '6.18': ('10', '4\n'), '6.15': ('10', '6\n'), '6.16': ('6', '9\n'), '6.12': ('6', '3\n'), '6.17': ('9', '3\n'), '6.14': ('10', '8\n'), '6.11': ('6', '8\n')}
```

but I don't know how to remove `'\n'` from the ends of my tuples.  This is really simple but I can't find out how to do this.  It's because I'm reading vertically from a file (hence the newline) but I don't want that `'\n'` in my dictionary.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you can and should use string methods over functions in the `string` module, so the third line becomes `line.split(',')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not working with a ridiculously large file, you can actually avoid having to use `.strip()` at all. If you read in the entire file as a string using `.read()` and then perform `.splitlines()` on that string.

Here is an example.  I commented out your code where I changed things. I changed the example not to use slicing in exchange for explicit variable assignment.

```
subject_dic = {}
inputFile = open(filename)

# Turn "line1\nline2\n" into ['line1', 'line2']
inputData = inputFile.read().splitlines()

#for line in inputFile:
for line in inputData:
    #split_line = string.split(line, ',')
    #subject_dic[split_line[0]] = tuple(split_line[1:3])
    mykey, myval1, myval2 = line.split(',') # Strings always have .split()
    subject_dic[mykey] = (myval1, myval2) # Explicit tuple assignment

print subject_dic
```

Outputs:

```
{'6.00': ('10', '1'),
 '6.01': ('5', '4'),
 '6.02': ('5', '6'),
 '6.03': ('2', '9'),
 '6.04': ('1', '2'),
 '6.05': ('1', '18'),
 '6.06': ('5', '19'),
 '6.07': ('2', '10'),
 '6.08': ('1', '10'),
 '6.09': ('3', '7'),
 '6.10': ('8', '18'),
 '6.11': ('6', '8'),
 '6.12': ('6', '3'),
 '6.13': ('9', '16'),
 '6.14': ('10', '8'),
 '6.15': ('10', '6'),
 '6.16': ('6', '9'),
 '6.17': ('9', '3'),
 '6.18': ('10', '4'),
 '6.19': ('8', '19')}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
split_line = split_line.strip()
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs).

Comment: Now my next question is how do I convert the tuple elements to integers? Is there a mapping function on tuples that does this? I can't find it.

Comment: Slightly better `split_line = line.strip().split()`.

Comment: @Glassjawed: Yes there is. It's named `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) on the lines to trim off the new lines.

str.strip([chars])

Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

Answer (score 1):

```
line = line.strip()
```

at the beginning  of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
subject_dic = {}
inputFile = open(filename) 
for line in map(lambda x: x.strip(), inputFile):
    split_line = string.split(line, ',')
    subject_dic[split_line[0]] = tuple(split_line[1:3])
print subject_dic
```